# Get encoding of a file in Windows

Tags: windows, encoding

This isn't really a programming question, is there a command line or Windows tool (Windows 7) to get the current encoding of a text file? Sure I can write a little C# app but I wanted to know if there is something already built in?

Comment: You can use a free utility called Encoding Recognizer (requires java). You can find it at http://mindprod.com/products2.html#ENCODINGRECOGNISER

Comment: **_Guess_ encoding of a file in Windows** is what the title should be. If you don't know in advance, you'll never be able to guess for certain.

Comment: @TomBlodget Your comment makes sense. Then how do the below answers work? Are they just guessing?

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Open up your file using regular old vanilla **Notepad** that comes with **Windows 7**.
It will show you the encoding of the file when you click "*Save As...*".
It'll look like this:
[image]

Whatever the default-selected encoding is, that is what your current encoding is for the file.

If it is UTF-8, you can change it to ANSI and click save to change the encoding (or visa-versa).

There are many different types of encodings, but this was all I needed when  our export files were in UTF-8 and the 3rd party required ANSI.  It was a onetime export, so Notepad fit the bill for me.

FYI: From my understanding I think "*Unicode*" (as listed in Notepad) is a misnomer for UTF-16.
More here on Notepad's "*Unicode*" option: [Windows 7 - UTF-8 and Unicode](https://superuser.com/questions/221593/windows-7-utf-8-and-unicode)

#### Update (06/14/2023):

Updated with screenshots of the newer Notepad and Notepad++

**Notepad** (Windows 10 & 11)**:**
   Bottom-Right Corner: [image]
   "*Save As...*" Dialog Box: [image]

**Notepad++:**
   Bottom-Right Corner: [image]
   "*Encoding*" Menu Item: [image]
   Far more Encoding options are available in NotePad++; should you need them.

#### Other (Mac/Linux/Win) Options:

I hear Windows 11 improved the performance of large 100+MB files to open much faster.
On the web I've read that Notepad++ is still the all around *large-file editor* champion.
However, (for those on **Mac** or **Linux**) here are some other contenders I found:
1). [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)
2). [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: there is no notepad on windows 8 and editor (which seems to be the replacement) does not have this functionality

Comment: @Alex, I do not use Win-8.  Performing a google search, I found this link: [Win-8 Notepad](https://echlinm.wordpress.com/2011/11/06/windows-8-start-menu-where-did-notepad-go/).  I hope you find it because I assure you, it's still there.

Comment: Thanks but on Windows 8.1 there is definitely no app called notepad. When you enter notepad in the search, "editor" appears. And this does not have that endoding dropdown and no menu for it either

Comment: This method does not work for files that are too large for Notepad to open. And that limit is reached much faster than other editors like Notepad++.
My Windows 8.1 does have Notepad. Look in %windir%\system32\notepad.exe maybe?

Comment: Notepad, as distributed with Windows systems, will crash on files over 64k.  If I were to trust the encoding listed in "Save as", then I'll need to trust that this 64.1k file is completely blank.  Unreliable.  Just look at that list in your image example: it doesn't even list the only encoding that Windows uses as default, CP1252!!!  So unreliable.

Comment: Notepad exists in Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Comment: Read this article if you are curious about all these: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Notepad is installed in ALL versions of Windows since Windows 3 at least.

Comment: In windows 10, its shortcut is in "Windows Accessories". To avoid searching for the shortcut, simply press Windows+R then type notepad.
And Notepad definitely works on files of all sizes, albeit slowly on files larger than 100MB. I've used it today to review 3MB log files.

Comment: I just used this to identify encoding on a 7MB text file in Windows 8.1. This is a good solution and the drawbacks mentioned in comments don't seem to apply in the real world.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Notepad is not for big files usage, but it does have the ability to open files larger than 64KB at least since XP. Only the version in Windows 98 and previous support a maximum of 64KB

Comment: One option is to download Notepad++. It is a very powerful free notepad and works as it was explained by @MikeTeeVee

Comment: Anyone knows how does Notepad's "ANSI" encoding map to CRAN's R read_delim() function encoding types?

Comment: @Alex In the bottom right of the editor you also see the encoding.

Answer (score 117):

If you have "git" or "Cygwin" on your Windows Machine, then go to the folder where your file is present and execute the command:

```
file *
```

This will give you the encoding details of all the files in that folder.

Comment: adding to your answer, If you only interested in specific file, you can use [grep command](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/grep-command-linux-unix-examples) to filter the results of `file *` command

Comment: Instead of just blindly running file command, the full command that answers this question is `file --mime-encoding` to get the encoding for the file

Comment: In 2020, the question is not cygwin anymore, it is wsl or wsl2. Cygwin is nearly dead.

Comment: In 2021, this works in git-bash (aka the shell that ships with "Git for Windows"). It uses MinGW, not Cygwin.

Answer (score 79):

The (Linux) command-line tool 'file' is available on Windows via GnuWin32:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm

If you have git installed, it's located in C:\Program Files\git\usr\bin.

Example:

```
    C:\Users\SH\Downloads\SquareRoot>file *
    _UpgradeReport_Files;         directory
    Debug;                        directory
    duration.h;                   ASCII C++ program text, with CRLF line terminators
    ipch;                         directory
    main.cpp;                     ASCII C program text, with CRLF line terminators
    Precision.txt;                ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
    Release;                      directory
    Speed.txt;                    ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
    SquareRoot.sdf;               data
    SquareRoot.sln;               UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with CRLF line terminators
    SquareRoot.sln.docstates.suo; PCX ver. 2.5 image data
    SquareRoot.suo;               CDF V2 Document, corrupt: Cannot read summary info
    SquareRoot.vcproj;            XML  document text
    SquareRoot.vcxproj;           XML document text
    SquareRoot.vcxproj.filters;   XML document text
    SquareRoot.vcxproj.user;      XML document text
    squarerootmethods.h;          ASCII C program text, with CRLF line terminators
    UpgradeLog.XML;               XML  document text

    C:\Users\SH\Downloads\SquareRoot>file --mime-encoding *
    _UpgradeReport_Files;         binary
    Debug;                        binary
    duration.h;                   us-ascii
    ipch;                         binary
    main.cpp;                     us-ascii
    Precision.txt;                us-ascii
    Release;                      binary
    Speed.txt;                    us-ascii
    SquareRoot.sdf;               binary
    SquareRoot.sln;               utf-8
    SquareRoot.sln.docstates.suo; binary
    SquareRoot.suo;               CDF V2 Document, corrupt: Cannot read summary infobinary
    SquareRoot.vcproj;            us-ascii
    SquareRoot.vcxproj;           utf-8
    SquareRoot.vcxproj.filters;   utf-8
    SquareRoot.vcxproj.user;      utf-8
    squarerootmethods.h;          us-ascii
    UpgradeLog.XML;               us-ascii
```

Comment: note that you probably need git 2.x for it, I don't have it with git 1.9.5

Comment: For my file it says "binary" :(

Comment: Unbelievable to have to revert to command line for basic operation, this is 2017, but it looks to do ok.

Comment: Like [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43489411/393280) says, you can also use the `file` command in **cygwin**. Any POSIX toolset for Windows should have `file`.

Comment: If you installed git for windows, it includes GIT BASH (bash emulator), which in turn includes the 'file' command. Just used it and it works. It's mentioned also in the next answer...

Comment: In windows if file name have space how can I deal with it?

Comment: tjorchrt: Put (double or single) quotes around it.

Answer (score 32):

Install git ( on Windows  you have to use git bash console). Type:

```
file --mime-encoding *
```

for all files in the current directory , or

```
file --mime-encoding */*
```

for the  files in all  subdirectories

Comment: Documentation link: https://linux.die.net/man/1/file

Comment: Nice answer.
However, `file --mime-encoding */*` will miss all files in `*/*/*`.
So you also need to run  `file --mime-encoding */*/*`, and so on, if you want to catch
*all* files in the whole subdirectory tree.

Answer (score 26):

Another tool that I found useful: [https://codeplexarchive.org/project/EncodingCheckerEXE] can be found [here](https://anonfile.com/L242k2rdb4/EncodingChecker_exe)

Comment: Really helpful to analyse multiple files

Comment: Instant answer even with very large files (as one would expect).

Comment: Works on current Windows 10.

Comment: can't figure out where the exe file is on that page. Is the link outdated?

Comment: same. Cant find exe

Comment: @MarkDeven Yeah. there is no EXE but if you have visual studio you can compile SLN file to create EXE. let me know if that doesn't work for you

Comment: @MarkDeven I have added path to exe in answer

Comment: [https://github.com/amrali-eg/EncodingChecker](https://github.com/amrali-eg/EncodingChecker) there is a modified version.

Comment: Yes, the github now host the latest version of this application.

Answer (score 22):

Here's my take how to detect the Unicode family of text encodings via BOM.  The accuracy of this method is low, as this method only works on text files (specifically Unicode files), and defaults to `ascii` when no BOM is present (like most text editors, the default would be `UTF8` if you want to match the HTTP/web ecosystem).

*Update 2018*: **I no longer recommend this method.**  I recommend using file.exe from GIT or *nix tools as recommended by @Sybren, and [I show how to do that via PowerShell in a later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816054/195755).

```bsh
# from https://gist.github.com/zommarin/1480974
function Get-FileEncoding($Path) {
    $bytes = [byte[]](Get-Content $Path -Encoding byte -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4)

    if(!$bytes) { return 'utf8' }

    switch -regex ('{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2}' -f $bytes[0],$bytes[1],$bytes[2],$bytes[3]) {
        '^efbbbf'   { return 'utf8' }
        '^2b2f76'   { return 'utf7' }
        '^fffe'     { return 'unicode' }
        '^feff'     { return 'bigendianunicode' }
        '^0000feff' { return 'utf32' }
        default     { return 'ascii' }
    }
}

dir ~\Documents\WindowsPowershell -File | 
    select Name,@{Name='Encoding';Expression={Get-FileEncoding $_.FullName}} | 
    ft -AutoSize
```

Recommendation: This can work reasonably well if the `dir`, `ls`, or `Get-ChildItem` only checks known text files, and when you're only looking for "bad encodings" from a known list of tools. (i.e. SQL Management Studio defaults to UTF16, which broke GIT auto-cr-lf for Windows, which was the default for many years.)

Comment: There are *many* variations of `Get-FileEncoding` on poshcode.  I've even reviewed punycode from python and nodejs, but this small version hits 80/20 for my usage (more like 99/1). If you're hosting other people's files I suggest you use `file` command from Syben's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34766140/195755) or another production-quality unicode decoder.

Comment: It should be added that this method works only if the BOM is present... which is not always the case

Comment: @Yepeekai The last line is `default` encoding (when no BOM).  For XML, JSON, and JavaScript the default is UTF8, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: @yzorg: but that's a brain dead way to do it. You're just lying to the user. At least most parsers make an educated guess.  If you can't make a guess just throw an error and tell them a BOM is required to use your code (and then go use another, smarter tool as many already exist).

Comment: @EdS. Sure, but seems impossible to know for sure.  I am the user when this code is run, so it is optimized for my use case (git hooks, or other scenarios where encodings break devops tools).

Comment: Sure, it is impossible to know _for sure_, but you can make an educated guess via heuristics. I get that this is your code, but once it hits e.g. SO for public consumption it's open to criticism.

Comment: @EdS. It's said in answer #2 and in comments of answer #1 that if you're looking for an "authoritative" encoding or file type to use `file.exe` from cygwin or GIT tools.  I also mention it in my response to other comments.  I follow that advice, see a later answer (also by me) https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816054/195755 for tips on using  `file.exe` from powershell.  Would you like me to include that qualifier in the body of my answer?

Comment: @yzorg: That's fine, but this is your answer. I commented on this, your answer, which says none of that.  You're saying I need to go read other answers and your comments elsewhere to better understand your own?

Answer (score 15):

A **simple** solution might be opening the file in Firefox.

1. Drag and drop the file into firefox
2. Press Ctrl+I to open the page info

and the text encoding will appear on the "Page Info" window.

[image]

**Note:**  If the file is not in txt format, just rename it to txt and try again.

P.S. For more info see [this](http://codeftw.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-find-character-encoding-of-text.html) article.

Comment: Looks like `View Page Info` is no longer around per [Firefox 88 has quietly removed these features](https://winaero.com/firefox-88-has-quietly-removed-these-features/) from April 2021. CTRL-I (Windows OS on Jan 2022) as a workaround

Answer (score 8):

I wrote the #4 answer (at time of writing).  But lately I have git installed on all my computers, so now I use @Sybren's solution.  Here is a new answer that makes that solution handy from powershell (without putting all of git/usr/bin in the PATH, which is too much clutter for me).

Add this to your `profile.ps1`:

```
$global:gitbin = 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin'
Set-Alias file.exe $gitbin\file.exe
```

And used like: `file.exe --mime-encoding *`.  You **must include .exe** in the command for PS alias to work.

But if you don't customize your PowerShell profile.ps1 I suggest you start with mine: https://gist.github.com/yzorg/8215221/8e38fd722a3dfc526bbe4668d1f3b08eb7c08be0
and save it to `~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell`.  It's safe to use on a computer without git, but will write warnings when git is not found.

The **.exe** in the command is also how I use `C:\WINDOWS\system32\where.exe` from powershell; and many other OS CLI commands that are "hidden by default" by powershell, *shrug*.

Comment: or you could just use `file` as your alias to file.exe instead of `file.exe` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @ferrell_io TL;DR: PS is based on .NET and .NET has File static class, and PS has enough confusing overloads with common EXEs that I use .exe to differentiate PS from Win EXE: `dir | where Size -lt 10000` vs `where.exe git`.

Comment: @ferrell_io I use `where.exe` to differentiate it from `where` in PS, which is a built-in alias for `Where-Object`.  Example:
`where.exe git*`
 vs 
`ls . | where Size -lt 10000`

Comment: @ferrell_io So I use the same pattern for `file.exe` vs .NET static class, which you might need in the same script that is detecting encoding.  Example:  `[File]::SetCreationTime("readme.md", [DateTime]::Now)`.

Comment: the better way is to add the folder to the `PATH` environment variable instead of using alias like this

Answer (score 4):

Some C code here for reliable ascii, bom's, and utf8 detection:  https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html

> Only ASCII, UTF-8 and encodings using a BOM (UTF-7 with BOM, UTF-8 with BOM,
>       UTF-16, and UTF-32) have reliable algorithms to get the encoding of a document. 
>       For all other encodings, you have to trust heuristics based on statistics.

EDIT:

A powershell version of a C# answer from:  [Effective way to find any file's Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding).  Only works with signatures (boms).

```
# get-encoding.ps1
param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] $filename)    
begin {
  # set .net current directoy                                                                                                   
  [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (pwd).path
}
process {
  $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($filename, 
    [System.Text.Encoding]::default,$true)
  $peek = $reader.Peek()
  $encoding = $reader.currentencoding
  $reader.close()
  [pscustomobject]@{Name=split-path $filename -leaf
                BodyName=$encoding.BodyName
                EncodingName=$encoding.EncodingName}
}


.\get-encoding chinese8.txt

Name         BodyName EncodingName
----         -------- ------------
chinese8.txt utf-8    Unicode (UTF-8)


get-childitem -file | .\get-encoding
```

Comment: @jeasoft Thanks.  I added in a fix to set the .net current directory.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246068/why-dont-net-objects-in-powershell-use-the-current-directory

Comment: This doesn't work for `ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-8, UTF-8 BOM`, does seem to work with `UTF-16, UTF-16 BE` though...

Comment: @not2qubit like I said only works with boms, including utf-8 bom

Comment: Interesting, but still not sure how that works...

Answer (score 4):

you can simply check that by opening your git bash on the file location then running the command `file -i file_name`

example

```sh
user filesData
$ file -i data.csv
data.csv: text/csv; charset=utf-8
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking for a Node.js/npm solution? Try [encoding-checker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding-checker):

```
npm install -g encoding-checker
```

#### Usage

```
Usage: encoding-checker [-p pattern] [-i encoding] [-v]
 
Options:
  --help                 Show help                                     [boolean]
  --version              Show version number                           [boolean]
  --pattern, -p, -d                                               [default: "*"]
  --ignore-encoding, -i                                            [default: ""]
  --verbose, -v                                                 [default: false]
```

#### Examples

Get encoding of all files in current directory:

```
encoding-checker
```

Return encoding of all `md` files in current directory:

```
encoding-checker -p "*.md"
```

Get encoding of all files in current directory and its subfolders (will take quite some time for huge folders; seemingly unresponsive):

```
encoding-checker -p "**"
```

For more examples refer to the [npm docu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding-checker) or the official [repository](https://github.com/piecioshka/encoding-checker).

Answer (score 2):

[EncodingChecker](https://github.com/amrali-eg/EncodingChecker)

File Encoding Checker is a GUI tool that allows you to validate the text encoding of one or more files. The tool can display the encoding for all selected files, or only the files that do not have the encodings you specify.

File Encoding Checker requires .NET 4 or above to run.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the solution listed above with Notepad, you can also open the file in Visual Studio, if you're using that. In Visual Studio, you can select "File > Advanced Save Options..."

The "Encoding:" combo box will tell you specifically which encoding is currently being used for the file. It has a lot more text encodings listed in there than Notepad does, so it's useful when dealing with various files from around the world and whatever else.

Just like Notepad, you can also change the encoding from the list of options there, and then saving the file after hitting "OK". You can also select the encoding you want through the "Save with Encoding..." option in the Save As dialog (by clicking the arrow next to the Save button).

Comment: Nice but when I try to open the file with Visual Studio, it always open the file in the associated text editor (Notepad++ for this kind of file extension).

Comment: @barbara.post that'd be something to do with your Visual Studio settings, I'd think. I've been able to access any plain text files of any type in Visual Studio. You've probably told it to just go to Notepad++ whenever it encounters a file with that extension. That's my thoughts, at least.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I have found to do this is VIM or Notepad++.

Comment: Unfortunately they're not "builtin" tools

Answer (score 0):

### Using Powershell

After many years of trying to get file encoding from native CMD/Powershell methods, and always having to resort to using (and installing) 3rd party software like `Cygwin`, `git-bash` and other external binaries, there is finally a native method.

Before, people go on complaining about all the ways this can fail, please understand that this tool is primarily to be used for identifying Text,Log, CSV and TAB type of files. Not binary files. In addition, the file encoding is mostly a guessing game, so the provided script is making some rudimentary guesses, that will certainly fail on large files. Feel free to test and give improved feedback in the gist.

To test this, I was dumping a bunch of weird garbage text into a string, and then exporting it using the available Windows Encodings.

`ASCII, BigEndianUnicode, BigEndianUTF32, OEM, Unicode, UTF7, UTF8, UTF8BOM, UTF8NoBOM, UTF32`

```
# The Garbage
$d=''; (33..126 && 161..252) | ForEach-Object { $c = $([char]$_); $d += ${c} }; $d = "1234 5678 ABCD EFGH`nCRLF: `r`nESC[ :`e[`nESC[m :`e[m`n`r`nASCII [22-126,161-252]:`n$d";

$elist=@('ASCII','BigEndianUnicode','BigEndianUTF32','OEM','Unicode','UTF7','UTF8','UTF8BOM','UTF8NoBOM','UTF32')
$elist | ForEach-Object { $ec=[string]($_); $fp = "zx_$ec.txt"; Write-Host -Fo DarkGray ("Encoding to file: {0}" -f $fp); $d | Out-File -Encoding $ec -FilePath $fp; }

# ls | encguess

 ascii           zx_ASCII.txt
 utf-16 BE       zx_BigEndianUnicode.txt
 utf-32 BE       zx_BigEndianUTF32.txt
 OEM (finds) : (3)
 OEM 437 ?       zx_OEM.txt
 utf-16 LE       zx_Unicode.txt
 utf-32 LE       zx_UTF32.txt
 utf-7           zx_UTF7.txt
 utf-8           zx_UTF8.txt
 utf-8 BOM       zx_UTF8BOM.txt
 utf-8           zx_UTF8NoBOM.txt
```

Here's is the code and it can also be found in the gist URL.

```
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
# GuessFileEncoding.ps1 - Guess File Encoding for Windows-11 using Powershell
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Author      : not2qubit
#   Date        : 2023-11-27
#   Version:    : 1.0.0
#   License:    : CC-BY-SA-4.0
#   URL:        : https://gist.github.com/eabase/d4f16c8c6535f3868d5dfb1efbde0e5a
#--------------------------------------------------------
#   Usage       : ls | encguess
#               : encguess .\somefile.txt
#--------------------------------------------------------
#   References: 
# 
#   [1] https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-7/list.htm
#   [2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers
#   [3] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
#   [4] https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797
#   [5] https://github.com/dankogai/p5-encode/blob/main/lib/Encode/Guess.pm
#
#--------------------------------------------------------
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/62511302/1147688

Function Find-Bytes([byte[]]$Bytes, [byte[]]$Search, [int]$Start, [Switch]$All) {
    For ($Index = $Start; $Index -le $Bytes.Length - $Search.Length ; $Index++) {
        For ($i = 0; $i -lt $Search.Length -and $Bytes[$Index + $i] -eq $Search[$i]; $i++) {}
        If ($i -ge $Search.Length) { 
            $Index
            If (!$All) { Return }
        } 
    }
}

function get_file_encoding {
    param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] $filename)    
    
    begin {
        # Use .NET to set current directory 
        [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = (pwd).path
    }
    
    process {
        
        function guess_encoding ($bytes) {
            # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Plan:     Do the easy checks first!
            # 1. scan whole file & check if there are no codes above [1-127] and excess of "?" (0x3f)  --> ASCII
            # 2. scan whole file & check if there are codes above [1-127]           --> ? ANSI/OEM/UTF-8
            # 3. scan whole file & check if there are many codes "2b41" &  char<127 --> UTF-7  --> "2b2f76" UTF-7 BOM
            # 4. scan whole file & check if there are many codes "c2 | c3"          --> UTF-8
            # ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            switch -regex ('{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}{3:x2}' -f $bytes[0],$bytes[1],$bytes[2],$bytes[3]) {
                # 1. Check UTF-8 BOM
                '^efbbbf'   { return 'utf-8 BOM' }          # UTF-8 BOM     (?)
                '^2b2f76'   { return 'utf-7 BOM' }          # UTF-7 BOM     (65000)
                
                # 2.  Check UTF-32 (BE|LE)
                '^fffe0000' { return 'utf-32 LE' }          # UTF-32 LE     (12000)
                '^0000feff' { return 'utf-32 BE' }          # UTF-32 BE     (12001)     'bigendianutf32'
                
                # 3.  Check UTF-16 (BE|LE)
                '^fffe'     { return 'utf-16 LE' }          # UTF-16 LE     (1200)      'unicode'
                '^feff'     { return 'utf-16 BE' }          # UTF-16 BE     (1201)      'bigendianunicode'
                
                default     { return 'unsure' }             # 
            }
        }
        
        function guess_again ($blob) {
            
            #-------------------------------
            # 1. Check if ASCII [0-127] (7-bit)
            #-------------------------------
            # (a) Check if using ASCII above 127
            $guess_ascii = 1
            foreach ($i in  $blob) { if ($i -gt 127) { $guess_ascii=0; break; } }
            
            # (b) Check if there are many consecutive "?"s. 
            #     That would indicate having erroneously saved a 
            #     ISO-8859-1 character containing file, as ASCII.
            
            #$b = [byte[]]("????".ToCharArray())
            #$n = (Find-Bytes -all $blob $b).Count
            #if ($n -gt 4) {}
            
            #-------------------------------
            # 2. Check for UTF-7 strings "2b41" (43 65)
            #-------------------------------
            
            $b = [byte[]]("+A".ToCharArray())
            $finds=(Find-Bytes -all $blob $b).Count
            $quart = [math]::Round(($blob.length)*0.05)
            #Write-Host -Fo DarkGray "  UTF-7 (quart,finds) : (${quart},${finds})"
            
            if ( ($finds -gt 10) -And ($guess_ascii -eq 1) ) { 
                return 'utf-7' 
            } elseif ($guess_ascii -eq 1) {
                return 'ascii'
            } 
            
            #-------------------------------
            # 3. Check for UTF-8 strings "c2|c3" (194,195)
            #-------------------------------
            # If > 25% are c2|c3, probably utf-8
            $b = [byte[]](0xc2)
            $c = [byte[]](0xc3)
            $f1=(Find-Bytes -all $blob $b).Count
            $f2=(Find-Bytes -all $blob $c).Count
            $quart = [math]::Round(($blob.length)*0.25)
            $finds = ($f1 + $f2)
            
            if ($finds -gt $quart) { return "utf-8" } 
            
            #-------------------------------
            # 4. Check for OEM Strings:
            #-------------------------------
            # Check for "4x" sequences of 'AAAA'(41), 'IIII'(49), 'OOOO'(4f)
            $n = 0
            #$oemlist = @(65,73,79)
            $oemlist = @('A','I','O')
            #$b = [byte[]](("$i"*4).ToCharArray())
            foreach ($i in $oemlist) {$b = [byte[]](("$i"*4).ToCharArray()); $n += (Find-Bytes -all $blob $b).Count  } 
            #$blob | Group-Object | Select Name, Count | Sort -Top 15 -Descending Count
            Write-Host -Fo DarkGray "  OEM (finds) : ($n)"
            
            if ($n -ge 3) { return "OEM 437 ?" }
            
            return "unknown"
        }
        
        $bytes = [byte[]](Get-Content $filename -AsByteStream -ReadCount 4 -TotalCount 4)
        
        if (!$bytes) { 
            $guess = 'failed' 
        } else {
            $guess = guess_encoding($bytes)
        }
        
        if ($guess -eq 'unsure') {
            # 28591  iso-8859-1  Western European (ISO) // Windows-1252
            $blob = [byte[]](Get-Content $filename -AsByteStream -ReadCount 0)
            $guess = guess_again($blob)
        }
        
        $name = $filename.Name
        Write-Host -Fo White ("  {0,-16}" -f $guess) -Non; Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow "$name"
    }
}

Set-Alias encguess get_file_encoding
```