# ReadAllText function in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, text, char

I have a text file which contains the char `¿`
when I use the `ReadAllText` function to get the txt file text:
the function changes the char `¿` to `?`
How can I get that char? Should I use another function?

Comment: Give us the corresponding code please.

Comment: Have you tried the ReadAllText(path, Encoding)? That might help

Comment: Hi since this is your first post on stack overflow. Please try to follow the guide lines. Please put your code up so we can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The file is likely in an encoding the method cannot detect automatically (most encodings cannot be reliably detected anyways). Use [the overload that lets you specify an encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143369(v=vs.110).aspx) and specify the correct encoding for the file.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the encoding as second parameter like:

```
File.ReadAllText("file path", Encoding.UTF8);
```

Here is the [list of encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Problem with encodings

Try to use `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` for [spanish characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089357/how-to-read-special-character-like-%C3%A9-%C3%A2-and-others-in-c-sharp).

```
File.ReadAllText("file path", Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));
```