# Reading a text from textfile(All languages)

Tags: c#

I am trying to read all text from textfile. Its working fine for English language and fails for Spanish, French, etc. I have to read any language from textfile. I am using **File.ReadAlltext(filepath,Encoding.UTF8)**. I tried UTF-8,Default,etc. But it fails to read, am getting some unwanted characters. Please give me a solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: fails in what way, what errors are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure you saved the file in UTF8 format?

Comment: @Mokchhya: Yes, In saved file, i can see the characters

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what encoding you file uses? If not then you can try out the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding). You can only hope for best when trying to find out encoding programmatically because the result can always bring surprises as there are many possibilities. Below is the code i picked up from that link.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines a text file's encoding by analyzing its byte order mark (BOM).
/// Defaults to ASCII when detection of the text file's endianness fails.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filename">The text file to analyze.</param>
/// <returns>The detected encoding.</returns>
public static Encoding GetEncoding(string filename)
{
    // Read the BOM
    var bom = new byte[4];
    using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)) file.Read(bom, 0, 4);

    // Analyze the BOM
    if (bom[0] == 0x2b && bom[1] == 0x2f && bom[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7;
    if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8;
    if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode; //UTF-16LE
    if (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; //UTF-16BE
    if (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff) return Encoding.UTF32;
    return Encoding.ASCII;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the file encoding for example using this https://code.google.com/p/chardetsharp/ library. 
And then convert to the desired.