# csvReader skips characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, csvhelper

I am reading a Csv file in a asp.net Web application to produce a report. The CsvReader element does not read in special characters such as ± or Σ.

```
            var avar = FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName;
            var myfile = File.OpenText(avar);
            CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(myfile);
            data = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
```

The reader skips the special characters mentioned above. Every other characters is read included characters surrounding the special characters. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to specify a text encoding for the CsvReader.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a little on your suggestions? This is my first web development project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use GetEncoding from this link [Effective way to find any file's Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding/19283954#19283954) to find the encoding of my file.

then, I set the configurations:

```
CsvConfiguration config = new CsvConfiguration();
config.Delimiter = ",";
Encoding enc = GetEncoding(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName);
config.Encoding = enc;
config.HasHeaderRecord = true;
config.QuoteNoFields = true;
```

Next, I use a FileStream to load file and send it to a StreamReader.

```
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(FileUploader.PostedFile.FileName);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(enc.HeaderName));
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
datas = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
```

All characters are readable when I load a file.  is an IEnumerable class