# How to check the response encoding of a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, encoding, utf-8

We delivered a WCF service with a custom binding which should return utf8.

Now the caller of the services says the service does not return utf8 encoded content.

We checked the header and that is ok(it says utf8) but the question is: how can I check if the response message itself is utf-8 encoded?

(I use soap ui to call the service, but other tools are ok too)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19283954/4558029). Should work for any kind of stream

Comment: Thanks, but then I will need to get the data from a C# program, hope to find a solution without building that

Comment: Since you tagged that question with c#, i assumed you wanted a programmatically solution

Comment: @lokusking understandable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use any network tools like wireshark or fiddler...but your encoding must be visible in the config- check with wcf config editor tool

Comment: Yeah, tried fiddler, but somehow my soapui requests aren't captured.

Comment: don't use localhost in your client config but the machine name if you test in local

Comment: I am calling a 'normal' uri for our test environment, so I thought that would be captured.

Comment: Managed to get my request in Fiddler, but there I can't find the encoding of the response, only the header (which says utf-8, but in theory the header and the actual response encoding can differ I guess?)

Comment: right, i don't find it too. You will perhaps have to go with wireshark ?

Comment: try if you copy/paste the response in notepad++ does it give you the encoding ? in the status bar it display the "detected" encoding i think