# How to detect encoding in a markdown file using program effectively , to get same encoding as shown in notepad++ ?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, markdown, jekyll

I have a set of markdown files to be passed to jekyll project , need to find the encoding format of them i.e UTF-8 with BOM or UTF-8 without BOM or ANSI using a program or a API .

if i pass the location of the files , the files have to be listed,read and the encoding should be produced as result .

Is there any Code or API for it ?

i have already tried the sr.CurrentEncoding for stream reader as mentioned in [Effective way to find any file's Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding) but the result varies with the result from a notepad++ result .

in notepad++ , the file encoding is shown as utf-8 , but from the program , the result is ANSII .

but i should get same result from both ways , so where the problem has occurred?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question , as i get different results from program and the notepad++ encoding . what shall i do now ?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?  If not, have you tried using:
      reader.Peek();    before
      using:  reader.CurrentEncoding;
  ?

Comment: yes , i had used peek method but if the file does not contain any special character , ANSI and UTF-8 is not distinguishabale

Comment: maybe you can research how notepad++ calculates their encoding