# How to convert huge text file from Unix to Windows quickly in .NET core

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .Net core, I have huge text files that need to be converted from Unix to Windows.

Since I can't load the file completly in memory (the files are too big), I read each byte one after the other, and when I encounter a LF, I output a LF+CR. This process works, but it takes a long time for huge files. Is there a more efficently way to do?

I thought about using a StreamReader, but the problem I'm having is that we don't know the source file encoding.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: hard to say how to increase the efficiency without seeing how you're reading the bytes.  Most efficient is likely reading the file into a buffer of some reasonable size and writing directly from that buffer to the new file - modifying whatever you need along the way. You might get better with a memory mapped file and spans but I don't know if the increase would be meaningful in your context.  But I also don't know how you're modifying content without knowing the encoding. Seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the specific files you're trying to process, I'd probably start off with something like the below and see if that gets me the results I want.

Depending on the specifics of your situation you may be able to do something more efficient, but if you're handling truly large datasets with unstructured text then it's usually a matter of throwing more powerful hardware at the problem if speed is still an issue.

You don't have to specify the Encoding to make use of the `StreamReader` class. Was there a specific problem with the reader you encountered?

```cs
const string inputFilePath = "";
const string outputFilePath = "";

using var sr = new StreamReader(inputFilePath);
using var sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath);

string line;

// Buffers each line into memory, but not the newline characters.
while ((line = await sr.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    // Write the contents of the string out to the "fixed" file (manually
    // specifying the line ending you want).
    await sw.WriteAsync(line + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is the StreamWriter. If I don't specify an output encoding, the StreamWriter uses UTF8 by default. The thing is, the input file could have another encoding...

Comment: OK I see what you mean now. So there's two options here.

If you *have* to preserve the encoding of the original file then you'll find a good discussion on how to get the encoding from any file [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding). You can then set this value as one of the constructor parameters on the StreamWriter class.

But I would also consider if this is necessary? Does using UTF8 cause you a problem later on?