# Read Windows Embedded Automotive Generated Binary File with C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, binary, windows-embedded

I have a 2011-spec Fiat Punto Evo and it have [Blue & Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%26Me) System equipped with Windows Embedded Automotive. It have a trip logging system called Eco:Drive. It logs all drive data to a USB storage with .bin file extension. Before, I can read the raw data via Eco:Drive app backed via Adobe Air. Now, the app is discontinued and I cant read the data. I try read the .bin file via C# as a binary file with .NET 5 console app but I cannot solve the encoding logic, it gives incomprehensible strings. For example:

**In binary array:**

> 95 153 96 13 66 64 71 48 73 45 0 5 12 95 152 176 13 66 64 71 64 73 109
> 0 5 12 95 159 80 29 66 64 71 80 73 37 46 5 12 95 154 64 29 66 64 71 96
> 73 29 0 5 12 95 159 104 13 66 64 71 128 73 5 45 5 12 95 158 232 13 66
> 64 71 144 72 221 0 5 12 95 154 16 13 66 64 71 160 73 29 0 5 12 95 153
> 248 13 66 64 71 176 73 5 0 5 12 95 153 40 21 66 64 71 192 72 237 0 5
> 12 95 158 104 13 66 64 71 208 72 205 0 5 12 95 152 248 13 66 64 71 224
> 72 197 45 5 12 95 152 112 13 66 64 71 240 72 197 0 5 12 95 152 80 13
> 66 64 72 0 72 197 0 5 12 95 152 48 13 66 64 72 16 72 197 0 5 12 95 152
> 88 13 66 128 72 32 72 189 0 5 12 95 152 96 13 66 128 72 48 72 173 0 5
> 12 95 159 120 5 66 128 72 64 72 181 0 5 12 95 152 96 13 66 128 72 80
> 72 181 0 5 12 95 159 176 5 66 128 72 96 72 181 0 5 12 95 152 24 13 66
> 128 72 112 72 173 0 5 12 95 152 72 13 66 128 72 128 72 181 0 5 12 95
> 152 128 13 66 128 72 144 72 189 0 5 12 95 152 128 13 66 128 72 160 72
> 181 0 5 12 95 152 112 13 66 128 72 176 72 173 0 5 12 95 159 32 5 66
> 128 72 192 72 181 0 5 12 95 152 160 13 66 128 72 208 72 173 0 5 12 95
> 159 112 5 66 128 72 224 72 213 0 5 12 95 152 240 13 66 128 72 240 73
> 85 0 5 12 95 152 248 29 66 128 73 16 73 53 0 5 12 95 155 144 29 66 128
> 73 32 72 237 0 5 12 95 154 160 13 66 128 73 48 72 205 0 5 12 95 153 0
> 13 66 128 73 64 72 197 0 5 12 95 159 128 5 66 128 73 80 72 189 0 5 12
> 95 159 136 5 66 128 73 96 72 189 0 5 12 95 159 224 5 66 128 73 112 72
> 173 0 5 12 95 152 192 13 66 128 73 128 72 181 0 5 12 95 152 8 13 66
> 128 73 144 72 181 0 5 12 95 153 96 13 66 128 73 160 72 197 0 5 12 95
> 152 112 13 66 128 121 144 64 25 208 72 67 144 64 0 4 2 128 174 42 33
> 64 128 0 0 0 0 0 0

**If I convert item to String via ASCII encoding (Shorted):**

> Y@F?ef?x????X?E?-O?x%X?@e6O? X?E??@X?@?OmjO??%X?E?      e?b?0%X?F
> ??)J?x%YF       ??(??p%YF       ?V?x
> [H@if?h?uV??[HP?]?B?h[H`%???p%Z??????[Hp??(R?Z?G?       E????p \@H?H????G      ?V?x ???\@H? ?S ??P\?I  ?a ??H\?I  ?n B??\?I0 ?z R??]I@  Ez V?(]@IP =o ]@I`    5h ]?Ip    -_ ]?I?    P ]?I?    > 4I?
> ^@I?    5??
> ???^?I??

**I use this code snippet:**

```
   using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, true))
                        {
                            var binary = new BinaryReader(streamReader.BaseStream);
                           
                            var text = binary.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(streamReader.BaseStream.Length));

                            
                            foreach (var item in text)
                            {
                                  Console.WriteLine(item);
                            }

                            var m = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(text);
                             Console.WriteLine(m);
                          
                        }
```

How can I convert these binaries to understandable string ? What is the true encoding ? Thanks.

P.S. : test file is [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AltcvLPGr965gvQG4ls_M51WPpfWvw?e=7J6SQ6).

***Edit:***

I converted to raw data using StreamReader with ASCII encoding (Shortened) :

> \u0006\u0001\u0006\u0001\u0000\u0048\u0049\u0043\u004e\u0050\u0057\u0033\u0035\u0031\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0046\u0031\u0039\u0039\u0046\u0050\u003f\u000d\u0001\u003f\u003f\u005f\u003f\u003f\u0058\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0040\u0030\u0009\u002d\u0000\u0005\u0018\u004f\u003f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Effective way to find any file's Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding)

Comment: @gunr2171 It says System.Text.ASCIIEncoding+ASCIIEncodingSealed (File encode is: US-ASCII in string.). Using ASCII is not decode already.

Comment: Most likely the data file is NOT encoded plain text. It is a custom binary file format. You will have to find out from someone (maybe at Blue & Me) what the file format is so you can then read the data from the file.