# CSVHelper C# generating wrong character

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper library to write to a CSV file. However, some of my CSV files have varying encodings, causing random characters to appear in the written data. Below is a code sample illustrating how I am currently handling this in my project. How could I solve it?

```
 public async Task WriteAsync<T>(string path, T record)
        {

            bool containsNewLines = ContainsNewLines(path);
            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
            using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                if (!containsNewLines)
                {
                    await csv.NextRecordAsync();
                }
                csv.WriteRecord(record);
                await csv.NextRecordAsync();
            }
        }

        private bool ContainsNewLines(string filePath)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return content.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
```

Comment: _"However, some of my CSV files have varying encodings"_ - how is that? You only seem to be writing UTF8?

Comment: Your code specifies UTF8, not varying encodings. Are you trying to *append* to existing files? In that case *the application code* must guess what the correct encoding is and specify that instead of UTF8. Except for Unicode files, there's no way to tell what encoding a file uses unless you read as much content as possible (possibly the entire file) until you find a byte that's invalid in one encoding or another. If the entire file contains English letters except the very last ,you'll have to read the entire file to the end

Comment: You are also aware that _for each call of your `WriteAsync`_ you read the whole file into memory? When the only thing you want to know is if the last character is a newline?

Comment: The real answer is to *not* use multiple encodings, but ensure everything is UTF8 (or UTF16, which contains an encoding identifier). Encoding-detection packages check for invalid bytes *and* for character distribution to guess the correct encoding for a file. Multiple encodings may map the same byte to different characters so even if you find 1 encoding that doesn't generate errors, you can't be certain it's the correct one

Comment: You can make an attempt to figure out the encoding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding. However, to be certain, you are going to have to ask the person uploading the file what the encoding of the file is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, there is no fail-safe way to determine the encoding of a file.  As [Panagiotis Kanavos states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852565/csvhelper-c-sharp-generating-wrong-character#comment135485074_76852565), the best answer is to either require all the files be of a single encoding, say `UTF8`, or else have the creator of the file somehow give you the encoding of the file.

That said, it is possible to take a guess at the encoding. Here is a modification of [Berthier Lemieux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52227667/2355006) for detecting file encoding.  The method reads the whole file and either determines the encoding by the byte order mark or assumes it is `UTF8` encoding.  If the reader throws an exception while reading as `UTF8`, the method then defaults to your preferred `ANSI` encoding.

```cs
public Encoding DetectFileEncoding(string fileName, Encoding defaultEncoding)
{
    var Utf8EncodingVerifier = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8", 
            new EncoderExceptionFallback(), new DecoderExceptionFallback());
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName, Utf8EncodingVerifier, 
            detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: true, bufferSize: 1024))
    {
        try
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                _ = reader.ReadLine();
            }
            return reader.CurrentEncoding;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Failed to decode the file using the BOM/UTF8. 
            // return default ANSI encoding
            return defaultEncoding;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use `DetectFileEncoding` to set the encoding for `StreamWriter`.  If your files are not likely to be `Latin1 (ISO-8859-1)` encoding, then you can use the default encoding that works best for you.

```cs
public async Task WriteAsync<T>(string path, T record)
{
    bool containsNewLines = ContainsNewLines(path);
    Encoding fileEncoding = DetectFileEncoding(path, Encoding.Latin1);

    using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, fileEncoding))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        if (!containsNewLines)
        {
            await csv.NextRecordAsync();
        }
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        await csv.NextRecordAsync();
    }
}
```