Can't get a return value from a method into a string in another method
I am trying to understand how to get the return value from one method to another method. Here is my code:
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        StrFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        CheckContent(StrFileName);
    }

private void CheckContent(string theFile)
{
    string fileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(theFile).ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("The encoding of the file is: " + fileEncoding, "Name Randomizer", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
}

public static Encoding GetEncoding(string filename)
{
    // Read the BOM
    var bom = new byte[4];
    using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        file.Read(bom, 0, 4);
    }

    // Analyze the BOM
    if (bom[0] == 0x2b && bom[1] == 0x2f && bom[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7;
    if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8;
    if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe && bom[2] == 0 && bom[3] == 0) return Encoding.UTF32; //UTF-32LE
    if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode; //UTF-16LE
    if (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode; //UTF-16BE
    if (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff) return new UTF32Encoding(true, true);  //UTF-32BE

    // We actually have no idea what the encoding is if we reach this point, so
    // you may wish to return null instead of defaulting to ASCII
    return Encoding.ASCII;
}

I am trying to determine the encoding of a file and display it in a MessageBox, but not sure how to put the returned value into a string variable (called fileEncoding).

Do you mean how to get the value of fileEncoding back to button1_Click, where CheckContent was called?

Change the return type from void to string for CheckContent and then just return fileEncoding? Then you can do string fileEncoding = CheckContent(StrFileName);? I assume I must be missing something; the question can't be that simple...

When I change the return type for the CheckContent, I get an error saying "not all code paths return a value."

You need to explicitly return the value at the bottom of the statement (otherwise, what value would be returned?)... . i.e. return fileEncoding;

The return values are correct. I am trying to get the file encoding value from the "public static Encoding GetEncoding(string filename)" method. I am sending the filename to that method, but I can't get it to return the type of encoding based upon the byte order mark (BOM). I am getting the code of the method from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825390/effective-way-to-find-any-files-encoding

It's still not super clear to me what exactly you're trying to do (beyond determining a file's encoding based on the BOM). What are you planning to do with the string that represents the encoding value of a file once you have it?

You already have the answer: string fileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(theFile).ToString();. It might be better to use EncodingName instead of ToString, but fileEncoding is ready to be put into a textbox.

This code is simply wrong. StreamReader already detects the BOM automatically while Encoding.ASCII refers to the 7-bit US-ASCII codepage that nobody uses. Latin1 isn't US-ASCII. There's absolutely no way to detect a file's encoding by checking just 4 bytes. A file may contain characters in the US-ASCII range until the middle or end of the file when values above 0x7F start appearing. And even then, you can't guess which encoding is used, as the same byte can be valid in multiple codepages.

To actually get a good estimate of the encoding use a package like UTF.Unkown. This, and similar packages in other languages, use the chardet algorithm first introduced by Mozilla to try and detect the encoding based on the statistics of byte values in the file compared to the letter frequencies in various languages/encodings (among other things)

The Encoding class has a string property 'EncodingName'.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF7.EncodingName);    // returns "Unicode (UTF-7)"
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName);    // returns "Unicode (UTF-8)"
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF32.EncodingName);   // returns "Unicode (UTF-32)"
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName);   // returns "US-ASCII"
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.EncodingName); // returns "Unicode"
}

So in your "CheckContent" function you can replace
string fileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(theFile).ToString();

with
string fileEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(theFile).EncodingName;

Or you can just edit "GetEncoding" to return the string name of the encoding
public static string GetEncoding(string filename)
{
    // Read the BOM
    var bom = new byte[4];
    using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        file.Read(bom, 0, 4);
    }

    // Analyze the BOM
    if (bom[0] == 0x2b && bom[1] == 0x2f && bom[2] == 0x76) return Encoding.UTF7.EncodingName;
    if (bom[0] == 0xef && bom[1] == 0xbb && bom[2] == 0xbf) return Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName;
    if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe && bom[2] == 0 && bom[3] == 0) return Encoding.UTF32.EncodingName; //UTF-32LE
    if (bom[0] == 0xff && bom[1] == 0xfe) return Encoding.Unicode.EncodingName; //UTF-16LE
    if (bom[0] == 0xfe && bom[1] == 0xff) return Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.EncodingName; //UTF-16BE
    if (bom[0] == 0 && bom[1] == 0 && bom[2] == 0xfe && bom[3] == 0xff) return new UTF32Encoding(true, true).EncodingName;  //UTF-32BE

    // We actually have no idea what the encoding is if we reach this point, so
    // you may wish to return null instead of defaulting to ASCII
    return Encoding.ASCII.EncodingName;
}

