# Mojolicious Template can't render © character

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1, mojolicious

I found error on Mojolicious Renderer when try to render © character (ascii: 169)

(also return error when try to render ascii larger than > 128)

```
Template "D:\sandbox\mojo\templates\BlueLeaves\index.html.ep" has invalid encoding. at D:/Perl64/site/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/EPLRenderer.pm line 44.
```

I tried to use both:

```
no utf8;
```

and

```
use utf8;
```

But always return same error message

Do you know how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the encoding of the template file to **utf8** file in my IDE.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464816/459233) and save your file as **utf8**

Answer (score 3):

Use UTF-8 encoding if possible -- that's always the best answer.

However if you really *can't* use UTF-8, you could replace the copyright symbol with it's HTML entity -- `&copy;`. That will render as the copyright symbol in the browser without you needing to actually send a UTF-8 character.

Preferable to use UTF-8 though if you can; it makes things a lot easier.