# Windows 7, Robocopy log asian or special characters

Tags: windows-7, character, robocopy

On windows 7, when I run Robocopy command, the log generated does not contain proper file names, if file names are having any asian or special characters.
Unilog switch produces gibrish log.
But on windows 10 logs are correct.
Any workaround or tool for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get unicode characters from robocopy process standard ouput in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069401/how-can-i-get-unicode-characters-from-robocopy-process-standard-ouput-in-c-sharp)

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/q/295934/96662