# Issue while reading file data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using C# (.NET 4.5) to read a text file which has some financial information. However, whenever I read negative values (ex: -$ 1,000.00) from the file, I see that the "-$" is converted to "�". Ex: – $1,000.00 to � 1,000.00. Why is this happening?

I tried using File.ReadAllText as well as reader.ReadToEnd() where reader is a StreamReader instance. I tried specifying the Encoding as well (UTF8). Nothing worked.

Comment: [Please check the encoding of the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows) and let us know what it is.

Comment: It shows the encoding as ANSI

Comment: @Thomas: ANSI is not UTF8! For a quick fix, resave the file as UTF8.

Comment: @JesseGood: thank you. I tried using Encoding.Default and it works for me now.

Comment: I see. `Encoding.Default` used the default encoding on your system which usually works. On the command prompt, type `chcp` to verify your system default code page. Often times its 1252, but for example mine is 932.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to format the string like this:

```
string curC = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo curFormat = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(curC).NumberFormat;
curFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 1;

num.ToString("c", curFormat);
// or string.Format(curFormat, "{0:c}", num);
```