# How to stop my output file from having Chinese characters?

Tags: java, jtable, byte, ascii, randomaccessfile

I'm trying to write into a RandomAccessFile by taking data from cells from a specific jtable. I convert the strings into bytes and then I implement the .write() function in order to write to the output file.

I made it so that I will be able to see what my output should be by printing bytes into the console. However when I check with my output file, I see Chinese character.

```
String data = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(r,c).toString();
                    byte[] BytedString = data.getBytes();
                    file.write(BytedString);                        
                    String s = new String(BytedString);
                    System.out.print(s+" ");
```

Did I do something wrong...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your code instead of using:

`String s = new String(BytedString);`

use:

`String s = new String(BytedString, "UTF-8");`

or

```
new String(BytedString, "US-ASCII");
new String(BytedString, "ISO-8859-1");
```

depending on your platform encoding.

```
String data = (String) table.getModel().getValueAt(r,c).toString();
                    byte[] BytedString = data.getBytes();
                    String s = new String(BytedString, "UTF-8");
                    file.writeChars(s);                        
                    System.out.print(s+" ");
```

Comment: Can I ask how does that help?

Comment: It should convert bytes to proper encoding in order to show proper characters.

Comment: It prints in perfect English. It's the when I'm trying to write is the problem. It's all in weird characters when I open my output file

Comment: Have you tested suggested changes with your files?

Comment: What do you mean? Have I checked my files after running the program? Yes it's still in Chinese characters

Comment: And putting those encodings?

Comment: Yes. My problem though is that its writing it in chinese characters or something similair. No problem with the console.

Comment: Let me rephrase, its writing Chinese character in my output file. Not my console :)

Comment: My file is a randomaccessfile so I cant write Strings

Comment: try writeChars instead of write.

Comment: Still for some reason is Chinese character

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: Im using Windows 10, and my IDE is Netbeans :)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows