# Writing to txt file multiple string, only last string saves?

Tags: python, save, screen-scraping

I know that this is a repeated question however from all answers on web I could not find the solution as all throwing error.
Simply trying to scrape headers from the web and save them to a txt file.
scraping code works well, however, it saves only last string bypassing all headers to the last one.
I have tried looping, putting writing code before scraping, appending to list etc, different method of scraping however all having the same issue.
please help.

here is my code

```
def nytscrap():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

url = "http://www.nytimes.com"

page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

for headlines in page.find_all("h2"):
    print(headlines.text.strip())

filename = "NYTHeads.txt" 
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
        file_object.write(str(headlines.text.strip()))
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your `for` loop runs, it overwrites the `headlines` variable, so when you get to writing to the file, the `headlines` variable only stores the last headline. An easy solution to this is to bring the `for` loop inside your `with` statement, like so:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    for headlines in page.find_all("h2"):
        print(headlines.text.strip())
        file_object.write(headlines.text.strip()+"\n") # write a newline after each headline
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for the quick response. I have tried that earlier however this throughout an error in the txt file that is not encoded as UTF-8 ?

Comment: Error! C:user\ txt file path... NYTHeads.txt is not YTF-8 encoded   Saving disabled.  see console for more details.     I have tried manually save the file in the correct format and the run it but still the same

Comment: It appears that this is a known issue in Jupyter notebooks, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35928426 and https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1572. However, it seems that the program does write to the file, it's just throwing an error when trying to read it.

Comment: OMG, you are right, when open the file outside Jupiter its all there!, lost 4 days trying to figure it out. so the corrected code is working, just Jupiter cant read the file... thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

here is full working code corrected as per advice.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def nytscrap():
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

url = "http://www.nytimes.com"

page = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")
filename = "NYTHeads.txt" 
with open(filename, 'w') as file_object:
    for headlines in page.find_all("h2"):
        print(headlines.text.strip())
        file_object.write(headlines.text.strip()+"\n")
```

this code will trough error in Jupiter work but when an 
opening file, however when file open outside Jupiter headers saved...