# Error in Adobe Brackets

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

All of my html and css files can be edited and viewed in Adobe Brackets up until a day ago when I got the following error when clicking on my file titled Portfolio.html and Portfolio.css Does anyone know how I can fix this?[image] (An error occurred when trying to open(filename.html) Brackets currently only supports UTF-8 encoded text files. I could use this information as soon as possible.

Comment: Change the file to UTF-8 encoding? Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets

Comment: This is also helpful, if you don't want to use the command line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows

Comment: jpopescuilan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows This really worked . Great and just in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the "UTF8 Converter" extension just open File > Extension Manager and search for "UTF."