# problems replacing €-symbol in strings

Tags: r, string, gsub

I want to replace every "€" in a string with "[euro]". Now this works perfectly fine with

```
    file.col.name <- gsub("€","[euro]", file.col.name, fixed = TRUE)
```

Now I am looping over column names from a csv-file and suddenly I have trouble with the string "total€". 
It works for other special character (#,?) but the € sign doesn't get recognized.

```
    grep("€",file.column.name)
```

also returns 0 and if I extract the last letter it prints "€" but

```
    print(lastletter(file.column.name) == "€")
```

returns FALSE. (lastletter is just a function to extract the last letter of a string.)

Does anyone have an idea why that happens and maybe an idea to solve it? I checked the class of "file.column.name" and it returns "character", also tried to convert it into a character again and stuff like that but didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. I can't reproduce with `DF <- iris; names(DF)[1] <- "total€"; grep("€", names(DF))`. Also share your system details, since this might be OS specific.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this problem as well, it only happens with this file. I'm working on windows 10 and using R studio Version 0.99.893

Answer (score 1):

Your encodings are probably mixed. Check the encodings of the files, then add the appropriate encoding to, e.g., `read.csv` using `fileEncoding="…"` as an argument.

If you are working under Unix/Linux, the `file` utility will tell you the encoding of text files. Otherwise, any editor should show you the encoding of the files.

Common encodings are UTF-8, ISO-8859-15 and windows-1252. Try `"UTF-8"`, `"windows-1252"` and `"latin-9"` as values for `fileEncoding` (the latter being a portable name for ISO-8859-15 according to R's documentation).

Comment: Thank you, how can I find out the file encodings? I removed all attributes from the file but this didn't make a change.

Comment: Have you tried googling? (I don't want to be rude, but detecting file encoding is a different question - and even not really on-topic on Stack Overflow, although [there is a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows).)

Comment: Sorry, I somehow assumed I had to check it with R. So it was encoded as "ANSI" and I set encoding = "ANSI" in read.csv with no success. Also I tried to save the file in other standards but this made it only worse. Which encoding could I try?

Comment: Hm I tried all of them and it makes no difference. Also changed the encoding in the file without success. Do you think using the "encoding" option would make sense? Else I will probably try on a different machine to see what's the issue.