# ViewComponent/PartialView get wrongly encoded and does not use UTF8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

My ViewComponent content is getting encoded for some reason, and I have not been able to find a way to render it properly.

In my view:

```
<vc:my-component></vc:my-component>
```

My component:

```
@model List<MyViewModel>

@foreach (var myViewModel in Model)
{
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
                ...
                <th>Miércoles</th>
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tbody-default">
            ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

}

The HTML gets rendered as:

```
<th>Mi�rcoles</th>
```

I have tried using this, but didn't make any difference:

```
<th>@Html.Raw("Miércoles")</th>
```

How can I make ASP.NET Core render the ViewComponent without encoding it?

EDIT:
The same happens with PartialViews

Comment: Do you have <meta charset="utf-8" /> in your _Layout.cshtml? 

Open your component in Notepad++. Maybe the file isn't being saved right. I just tried putting Miércoles in my viewcomponent and it worked.

Comment: @PaulTotzke Notepad (don't have ++ here) shows the é is correctly saved, and I do have that line (first one right below <head>). This do works on Views and PartialViews, though, only the ViewComponents (two of them) are giving the problem

Comment: Can you add this view component with a PartialView where this is working on the same page? Is this vc being sent via ajax? Copy the text from a working page to your view component?

Comment: @PaulTotzke No, the component is rendered as a TagHelper or as a Component (server-side, no ajax). I will try tonight using a PartialView instead and let you know

Comment: @PaulTotzke well, this is weird, the same happens for PartialViews

Comment: @PaulTotzke however, if I paste the contents onto the main page, it works just fine

Comment: Can you throw an example up on github or somewhere?

Comment: @PaulTotzke you may want to see this thread: https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most stupid bug ever.

Since for new projects everything goes just fine, I decided I'd try to create a new project and copy my files. Guess what? **Same problem arose**.
After childishly copying the text to one of the working projects, saving the file and copying the saved file to the project with problems, **it worked just fine**.

I find it completely weird that VS, Notepad and Notepad++ can open the file just fine, but ASP.NET Core can't.

So, solution? Copy the data over and replace the files...

Comment: My guess is that the old files are encoded differently. Open both files in plain old notepad and go to'Save As' to check how each are being encoded.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows

Comment: @PaulTotzke They are literally the same, and they are not "old" files, they were created at the same time as most of my views/project (last weekend!).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
Even placing the encode on the Layout Page, Partial View did not work.

To solve this, I had to change the file's encode as follows:

**1 - Broken page**

[image]

**2 - Open the folder where the file is located**

[image]

**3 - Open the file that has the characters that break, in a notepad**

[image]

**4 - Click in (File -> Save As)**

[image]

**5 - Change encode to UTF8 and Save the file**

[image]

**6 - Check the result**

[image]

See.. this solution also works with JavaScript.

Comment: If you have the time, you can edit your answer such that instead of showing URL, you can display the image directly using `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` with `[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwpmd.png`

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I did it for Flávio. New users can only link to images until they have enough reputation, and I don't expect anyone to do all that markdown syntax when for someone with enough reputation is just a click :)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Didn't know until now, thanks for your help and contribution.