# Encoding of Files for PHP project

Tags: php, html, unicode, encoding

I am developing a php project which is in HTML5. Following is the meta used for all pages in my website.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I am coding in windows machine using NetBeans. I was not really aware of encoding of the files. Since the code was working fine, i was not giving importance for this.

However, based on some of the questions in stackoverflow, I could understand more about encoding. I noticed that many php/js/css files of my project are saved in UTF-8 encoding whereas some php/js/css files are saved in ANSI encoding. *(to understand this, i opened the file in notepad, clicked on save as and checked the default encoding shown)*.

It seems the files in which I pasted some of the unicode characters were autosaved in UTF-8 and all other files were saved in ANSI encoding *(I guess it might be Windows-1252)*. All this happened even though I set project preference as UTF-8 in netbeans.

Is it required to save those files *(files which does not use unicode)* also to UTF-8 as my html meta says UTF-8? *(Note that there are no issues when I tested my website, but my testing was from a windows machine)*

I am also curious to know, how the browser render the web page correctly though some of the php files are saved in ANSI but served with meta UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

> (to understand this, i opened the file in notepad, clicked on save as and checked the default encoding shown).

This isn't an accurate way of checking the encoding of a file.

Files which contain only ASCII characters -- like most CSS and Javascript source files! -- are valid in most text encodings. Notepad will call them "ANSI" because that's its default, but they're also perfectly valid as UTF-8. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: does it mean, files containing only ASCII characters are same in UTF-8 and ANSI?

Comment: thanks for your answer. got this "A UTF-8 file that contains only ASCII characters is identical to an ASCII file" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unicode_encodings). But then I am surprised why text editors are still showing encoding option (with ansi, uft8 etc.) for such files.

Comment: notepad approach is the selected answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows

Comment: @Kiran Correct. The differences between most of the common text encodings (including UTF-8 and ANSI) only come into play when a file contains non-ASCII characters.