# Reading Excel file with utf-8 python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to open and read an excel file with *pd.read_excel* using utf-8 (so other languages could be read) as in *read_csv* the encodings can be set to utf-8, is it possible somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read \_excel: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 14: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647122/pandas-read-excel-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa8-in-position-14-invalid)

Comment: If you're opening an actual Excel file (.xlsx) I'm not sure you can change the decoding.  But the characters should come back correct regardless.  What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You may pass an open file:

```py
with open("file_path", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    pd.read_excel(f)
```

I didn't find a reference in the docs but a quick look in pandas code suggests ["utf-8" might be the default](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/73c68257545b5f8530b7044f56647bd2db92e2ba/pandas/io/common.py#L243) already.

Comment: Thank you! it seems I have a problem when trying to use the values (from the excel file) for text in kivy labels for example, so the codec does work, how can I fix it?