# Importing a file from a subfolder with read_csv : how to get it to work with engine='c' ? (UnicodeDecodeError)

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to read a csv file which is in a sunfolder of the current folder. I am on a Windows PC.

If I run:

```
df=pd.read_csv("subfolder//file.csv")
```

I get:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position
>   16: invalid start byte

If I run:

```
df=pd.read_csv("subfolder//file.csv", engine='python')
```

It works.

- Why????
- Isn't there a way to use c as the engine? It's meant to be faster

Comment: Could you csv file contain a SUPERSCRIPT TWO character U+00B2 `²`? If the answer is yes, it is probably Latin1 or cp1252 encoded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because read_csv is trying to read the file in "UTF-8" format while your file is clearly in a different format. To detect the encoding in Windows, you can look at this.
[Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows)

After you found out the file's encoding format, you can give an argument of the encoding type to the read_csv function. e.g.

```
df=pd.read_csv("subfolder//file.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: So this means that engine='c' causes encoding to default to 'utf-8', while engine='python' means a different encoding? I double checked https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html and none of this seems to be documented explicitly - as is unfortunately all too common in the beautiful world of Python...

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous I don't know about the current situation explicitly, but the error you are getting is an error of encoding conflict, and I suspect this might be the case. Have you checked your file's encoding yet?

Comment: Yes, if I set encoding='latin1' it works. Thanks for the help. PS still frustrated at the how much documentation sucks in the world of Python!