# how can I solve the problem with accents even if I already used a charset = UTF-8?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
  pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Library Management</title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <jsp:include page='menu.jsp'></jsp:include>
  <main>
    <section class="content">
      <div class="page-announce valign-wrapper">
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse valign hide-on-large-only"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <h1 class="page-announce-text valign">Fiche livre</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="container">
      <h5>Crèation d'un nouveau livre</h5>
        <div class="row">
          <form action="livre_add" method="post" class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col m12 s12">
                <input id="titre" type="text" name="titre">
                <label for="titre">Titre</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="auteur" type="text" name="auteur">
                <label for="auteur">Auteur</label>
              </div>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input id="isbn" type="text" name="isbn">
                <label for="isbn">ISBN 13</label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row center">
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange" type="reset">Annuler</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <jsp:include page='footer.jsp'></jsp:include>
</body>
</html>
```

That's a file in .jsp that is a class to visualize one function of the program .
I have a problem when I open the browser, the accents are decoded as not found even if I have used a UTF-8 charset and  statement to print Crèation d'un nouveau livre .

Comment: Is the file saved in utf-8? Does the response header specify utf-8 when viewed in browser dev tools?

Comment: I don 't know. How can I do that?

Comment: [Get encoding of a file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows)