# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 38: invalid start byte

Tags: python, unicode, error-handling, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I get the error

```
      print("blablablablabla ", str(mode), " am string ende in blablabla für das symbol ", str(sym)," existiert nicht.")                  
                                     ^

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 38: invalid start byte
```

But at nearly every string. Suddenly, out of nowhere.
This code lines existed since days and didnt throw an error, till yesterday.
What todo?

EDIT: (might be useful)
I noticed that it also comes up when using strings like "ü ö ä".

Comment: Can you print your full error code? That ü looks like it might be causing some problems.

Comment: What is `mode` and `sym`??

Comment: @MarkMeyer                       strings which do not contain any äüö

Comment: @MarkMeyer I see what you mean but yes it is. I commented that line out and it did the exact same error on the other 60 print() calls. At one of them i changed ü to u and suddenly it worked. but for the other ones i have no idea and i also need to use äöü again. :/

Comment: Is your python source file utf-8 encoded?

Comment: @MarkMeyer idk, How to check that?

Comment: That will depend on the editor you are using. In VSCode there is a menu at the bottom of the window to see/change. You can [check in windows with notepad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows). You can also set the encoding of a file by putting something like this at the top: `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` so python interprets it correctly.

Comment: Its Iso 8859-1. When I open a new file in UTF8 it gives different "errors" which look like prints (because of the white color). Btw I am using spyder  EDIT: sys.getdefaultencoding() says, that its actually utf-8, sorry

Comment: even after adding # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

Comment: There is a reason why everyone tries to use utf-8 for everything. Encodings are a pain. Adding `# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-` at the top might help. Honestly, I would take the time to recreate the source file in UTF-8.

Comment: this makes up different errors: not being able to import specific modules. 
ImportError: cannot import name 'feature_extraction' from 'feature_extraction' (D:/Arc/Arc_Project\Architecture\_2_Feature_Extraction\feature_extraction.py)

Comment: even when i add # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*- to the top of the module

Comment: that error was related to something different. Looks like it works now.