# Read a csv file in python correctly using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tnXC6Z7opPH61BANAhpBCe620jBSz8bM/view?usp=sharing) using read_csv in pandas(python).
But I am not able to capture all columns.
Can you help?

Here is the code:

```
file = r'path of file'
df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='cp1252', on_bad_lines='skip')
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not able to capture all columns"? What's the expected result? What result are you actually getting? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: if you open the file in excel or notepad++ you will see that there are 161 columsn and the code can capture only 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to read your file, and I first noticed that the encoding you specified does not correspond to the one used in your file. I also noticed that the separator is not a comma (`,`) but a tab (`\t`).

First, to get the file encoding (in linux), you just need to run:

```
$ file -i kopie.csv 
kopie.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

In Python:

```
import pandas as pd

path_to_file = 'kopie.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, encoding='utf-16le', sep='\t')
```

And when I print the shape of the loaded dataframe:

```
>>> df.shape
(869, 161)
```

Comment: how to find the encoding in windows?

Comment: it is less obvious, check this SO page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows