# R pandoc cannot compile a poster with posterdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to compile a poster with posterdown. It was working about a week ago, and I tried removing the text I added in between to see if that was the issue, but it doesn't appear to be.

Below is the error message I get:

```
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\x80': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.decodeUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
Closing browser
Cleaning browser working directory
Execution halted
```

And here is the beginning of my .Rmd:

````
---
title: <div style='margin:50px'> Our title</div> 
font_family: Calibri
poster_height: "47.24in"
poster_width: "35.43in"
author:
  - name: Author1 Name
  - name: Author2 Name
  - name: Author3 Name

column_numbers: 2

#logoleft_name: ./figures/phase.png

title_textsize: "78px"
author_textsize: "32px"
affiliation_textsize: "15px" 
body_textsize: "40px"

output: 
  posterdown::posterdown_html:
    self_contained: true
knit: pagedown::chrome_print
bibliography: packages.bib
---

\```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, encoding = 'UTF-8')

\```

(Above, I do not truly have the "\" characters, I just added it to post the question to stack overflow.)

# Title1

The only special character I am using in the poster is the sign '%'.
````

Any idea? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Chances are you're saving (or pasting) your text from an editor with other than UTF-8 endoding, e.g. when using Office products. Here's a description of saving text from MS-Word in UTF-8: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/save-word-docx-as-txt-with-utf-8-encoding/39442032-b160-4975-bbf0-877d8f0c4bd7 and here (maybe more helpful) to detect encoding and change it with standard Win text editor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I checked and no, it is not the case here. 
I suspect a parameter in my Rstudio / R / Mac / Google Chrome, because compilation was working a week ago and it is no longer working.
I tried reverting (from GitHub history) to a previous version to confirm, and indeed, same issue.

Cleaning my environment does not help.