# How can I write utf-8 characters to a csv file with C?

Tags: c, excel, csv, utf-8, printf

How can I write UTF-8 characters to a **CSV** file in C? I want to write letters such as `Ş`, `Ğ` or `İ`. Also I cannot write in different columns. There is something wrong with my PC, I guess: it does write all the data in a single cell even with such simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file = fopen("veriler.csv", "w");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Dosya açma hatası!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // CSV dosyasına verileri yazma
    fprintf(file, "Ad, Soyad, Yaş\n");
    fprintf(file, "John, Doe, 30\n");
    fprintf(file, "Jane, Smith, 25\n");

    fclose(file);
    printf("CSV dosyası oluşturuldu.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your CSV reader treats semicolons as the separator??? `fprintf(file, "Ad; Soyad; Yaş\n");`

Comment: ı love this site <3 :D it worked. and do u know how can ı write utf-8 character such as "Ş"

Comment: hmmm ... it should work just by simply writing the source file in UTF-8 (not ANSI, not ISO-8859-1, not anything else). Or write the unicode point encoded `fprintf(file, "==> \xc5\x9e <==")` xD

Comment: tbh ı didnt get the solution. there's a json file that includes utf-8 characters. ı have made to read them from it. and now ı gotta print them into a csv file as utf-8. its my college homework for oop course. can u give me an example to make it ?

Comment: Should work without doing anything special... `fgets(...)` (or whatever) then `fputs(...)` (or whatever) should keep the same encoding

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work. it writes something meaingless characters instead of them.

Comment: Make sure your file encodings match your expectation! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710374/get-encoding-of-a-file-in-windows **EVERYTHING** should be in the same encoding

Comment: this can work on my pc but thats the goal of project ı guess. it wont be working on teacher's pc cuz ı cant change her encoding. ı gotta solve this in my code :/

Comment: If your teacher json file is UTF-8 encoded (as it should!) there is nothing for you to do (but do make sure your C source file is UTF-8)... if it isn't there is (basically) nothing you can do. Unless you know beforehand what is the original encoding.

Comment: Also ... what will you do if your teacher CSV reader expects commas as separator? Maybe you should configure yours to accept commas? After all, it's "**Comma** Separated Values"!

Comment: yes ur right ima try it also , but firstly i gotta find a way for utf-8 issue :/

Comment: Well, it does already at least on Libre Office, you might have problem with csv reader. `Sam  Smith 25  Ş Ğ Ö Ç` and with raw `Sam, Smith, 25, Ş,Ğ,Ö,Ç `  and `fprintf(file, "Sam, Smith, 25, Ş,Ğ,Ö,Ç\n");` .

Comment: Try `"Ad, Soyad, Yaş\n"` --> `u8"Ad, Soyad, Yaş\n"`.  (others too.)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate issues in your question:

- The CSV file format has many variants: the column separator can be `,` as the name *Comma Separated Values* suggests, or `;` as is commonly used in various countries.  When you import the CSV file into another tool such as Excel, you should check what convention they use for the column separator.
- The character encoding used to represent non ASCII characters such as `Ş`, `Ğ` or `İ` must be consistent across the various tools involved in your environment: the source code editor, the compiler, the files you read the data from (JSON mandates the use of UTF-8), the operating system configuration (in particular the locale support), the tool used to view the CSV file, the terminal, the tools you import the CSV file into (Excel...).  If they all use the same encoding, eg: UTF-8, you should be fine, but on Windows systems, UTF-8 support is still not universal for historical reasons.  You are using a Turkish locale with may use an 8-bit encoding such as ISO-8859-9, or the Windows specific Code page 857, which are not compatible with UTF-8.

The recommended approach for non-ASCII textual contents is now to use UTF-8 (to encode Unicode code points) because the same standard can be used for all human languages, hence can be considered universal.

The locale still determines some specific variants in your case, such as Turkish specific case conversions:

- `i` converts to uppercase `İ` instead of `I`
- `I` converts to lowercase `ı` instead of `i`.

Consequently, I recommend you look into the configuration of all the tools mentioned above and try and select UTF-8 as the default encoding.  If this is not possible, try and select the same encoding where possible and use translation filters to convert the file contents where needed.

Comment: Nicely said.  Aside: the comma (,) character also needs to be cared for when it appears in normal text so a new cell/column isn't inadvertantly created.

Comment: ı still cant write utf-8 characters . ı guess ı am unskillful

Comment: @muratkavak: I would more likely blame the OS you are using, which seems unhelpful.