detect text file encoding in powershell
Using Powershell, how can I detect the text encoding of a file?
For example, I want to know the text encoding for the various .log files under path C:\Windows.
I can list those files easily enough
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.log' -Path "C:\Windows" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

But how could I also detect the text encoding for each file?  Is there Powershell cmdlet like Get-FileEncoding?

For PowerShell specific, see the answer in there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28079177/1701026
