# Batch convert latin-1 files to utf-8 using iconv

Tags: shell, character-encoding, iconv

I'm having this one PHP project on my OSX which is in latin1 -encoding. Now I need to convert files to UTF8. I'm not much a shell coder and I tried something I found from internet:

```
mkdir new  
for a in `ls -R *`; do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$a" >new/"$a" ; done
```

But that does not create the directory structure and it gives me heck load of errors when run. Can anyone come up with neat solution?

Comment: It tries to handle directories as files and iconv gives "not such file" -errors.

Comment: read my answer about enconv in thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310571/how-to-change-encoding-in-many-files/9310668#9310668

Answer (score 49):

You shouldn't use `ls` like that and a `for` loop is not appropriate either. Also, the destination directory should be outside the source directory.

```
mkdir /path/to/destination
find . -type f -exec iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "{}" -o /path/to/destination/"{}" \;
```

No need for a loop. The `-type f` option includes files and excludes directories.

**Edit:**

The OS X version of `iconv` doesn't have the `-o` option. Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "{}" > /path/to/destination/"{}"' \;
```

Comment: I used this script with no luck. For exact parameters and results, see http://pastebin.com/U2D0PpWr . There was lots of output for each file (it printed them on screen) and error messages for each file, but i guess you get the idea from that one. I'd be grateful if you'd develop this a bit further :)

Comment: This doesn't work if the file exists several subdirectories down because the echo or `-o` path says "No such file or directory" because it does not create the parent directories in the output location.

Comment: If you have created a subfolder, than add `find . -maxdepth 1 …` to let it find _only_ files in the present directory level, e.g.: `mkdir ./utf-8 && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.tex' -exec iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "{}" -o ./utf-8/"{}" ";" `

Answer (score 26):

This converts all files with the `.php` filename extension - in the current directory and its subdirectories - preserving the directory structure:

```bash
find . -name "*.php" -exec sh -c "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 '{}' > '{}'.utf8"  \; -exec sh -c "mv '{}.utf8' '{}'" \;
```

Notes:

To get a list of files that will be targeted beforehand, just run the command without the `-exec` flags (like this: `find . -name "*.php"`). Making a backup is a good idea.

Using `sh` like this allows piping and redirecting with -exec, which is necessary because not all versions of iconv support the `-o` flag.

Adding `.utf8` to the filename of the output and then removing it might seem strange but it is necessary. Using the same name for output and input files can cause the following problems:

- For large files (around 30 KB in my experience) it causes core dump (or `termination by signal 7`)
- Some versions of iconv seem to create the output-file before they read the input file, which means that if the input and output files have the same name, the input file is overwritten with an empty file before it is read.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks!  However, when not all files are in Latin 1, how is it possible to only convert the files which need to?  IOW, how to add the check with the `file` command?

Comment: A file is just a series of bytes, whether they make more sense interpreted as UTF-8 symbols or Latin 1 symbols only a human can know. However, if you are using the appearance of a certain symbol - for an example `Ã` - to determine whether a file must be re-encoded or not you can filter the files with`grep` and rencode with `xargs`, like: `grep --files-with-matches --recursive 'Ã' | xargs "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} > {}.utf8  ; -exec mv {}.utf8 {}"` (note: this code is untested, and make sure your shell is using UTF-8)

Answer (score 22):

Some good answers, but I found this a lot easier in my case with a nested directory of hundreds of files to convert:

### WARNING: This will write the files in place, so make a backup

```
$ vim $(find . -type f)

# in vim, go into command mode (:)
:set nomore
:bufdo set fileencoding=utf8 | w
```

Comment: You don't have to enter vim to do this. The following command does the same thing: `vim "+set nomore" "+bufdo set fileencoding=utf8 | w" "+q" $(find . -type f)`

Comment: @UTF_or_Death This is nice, but it doesn't work for file names with spaces. :(

Comment: @user1093967 I tried to find a solution but couldn't - tried piping this into sed and adding quotation marks, but that doesn't do the trick. Maybe the solution lies within the documentation for `find`. However, this works without any problem in fish shell, but I stopped using bash a long time ago because of constant weirdness like this

Comment: This has a side effect of adding a line feed at the end of the file if it's missing.

Answer (score 12):

To convert a complete directory tree recursively from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 including the creation of subdirectories none of the short solutions above worked for me because the directory structure was not created in the target. Based on Dennis Williamsons answer I came up with the following solution:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 't="/tmp/dest"; mkdir -p "$t/`dirname {}`"; iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 "{}" > "$t/{}"' \;
```

It will create a clone of the current directory subtree in `/tmp/dest` (adjust to your needs) including all subdirectories and with all `iso-8859-1` files converted to `utf-8`. Tested on macosx.

Btw: Check your file encodings with:

```
file -I file.php
```

to get the encoding information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's actually `file -i` to check a file's encoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot - that was perfect :-) (Debian Unix in my case)

Comment: I would add -iname '*.php':  find . -type f -iname '*.php' -exec bash -c 't="/tmp/dest"; mkdir -p "$t/`dirname {}`"; iconv -futf8 -tl1 "{}" > "$t/{}"' \;

Answer (score 7):

I create the following script that (i) backups all tex files in directory "converted", (ii) checks the encoding of every tex file, and (iii) converts to UTF-8 only the tex files in the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

```
FILES=*.tex
for f in $FILES
do
  filename="${f%.*}"
  echo -n "$f"
#file -I $f
  if file -I $f | grep -wq "iso-8859-1"
  then
    mkdir -p converted
    cp $f ./converted
    iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 $f > "${filename}_utf8.tex"
    mv "${filename}_utf8.tex" $f
    echo ": CONVERTED TO UTF-8."
  else
    echo ": UTF-8 ALREADY."
  fi
done
```

Comment: +!1 that's the correct solution, because I remember having troubles when a file was already utf-8, and yes it was a "mixed" project with iso-8859-1 and utf8 files. So I came up with a very similar solution. I added my answer.

Answer (score 6):

If all the files you have to convert are .php you could use the following, which is recursive by default:

```
for a in $(find . -name "*.php"); do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$a" >new/"$a" ; done
```

I believe your errors were due to the fact that `ls -R` also produces an output that might not be recognized by iconv as a valid filename, something like `./my/dir/structure:`

Comment: Or this which reuses the original file names:

`$ for a in $(find . -name "*.java"); do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$a" >"$a".utf8 ; done`

`$ for a in $(find . -name "*.java.utf8"); do mv "$a" `dirname "$a"`/`basename "$a" .utf8`; done`

Answer (score 6):

On unix.stackexchange.com a similar question was asked, and user manatwork suggested recode which does the trick very nicely.

I've been using it to convert ucs-2 to utf-8 in place

```
recode ucs-2..utf-8 *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Everything's fine with the above answers, but if this is a "mixed" project, i.e. there are already UTF8 files, then we may get into trouble, therefore here's my solution, I'm checking file encoding first.

```
#!/bin/bash
# file name: to_utf8

# current encoding:
encoding=$(file -i "$1" | sed "s/.*charset=\(.*\)$/\1/")

if [  "${encoding}" = "iso-8859-1" ] || [ "${encoding}" = "iso-8859-2" ]; 
then
echo "recoding from ${encoding} to UTF-8 file : $1"
recode ISO-8859-2..UTF-8 "$1"
fi

#example:
#find . -name "*.php" -exec to_utf8 {} \;
```

Answer (score 3):

On Windows Git Bash, I got these errors with several of the proposed solutions:

- `find: Only one instance of {} is supported with -exec ... +`
- `find: In ‘-exec ... {} +’ the ‘{}’ must appear by itself, but you specified ‘source={};`...’

But that (a mix of other proposed solutions) worked:

```
for fileToConvert in $(find . -type f -name \*.js); do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$fileToConvert" >~/temp-iconv.txt ; mv -f ~/temp-iconv.txt "$fileToConvert" ; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mkdir -p "${a%/*}";` before iconv.

Note that you are using a potentially dangerous `for` construct when there are spaces in filenames, see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs -I {} echo "iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 \"{}\" > \"{}-utf8.php\""
```

Comment: increments the file name...ex: \"{}-utf8.php\"

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers of Dennis Williamson and Alberto Zaccagni, I came up with the following script that converts all files of the specified file type from all subdirectories. The output is then collected in one folder that is given by `/path/to/destination`

```
mkdir /path/to/destination
for a in $(find . -name "*.php"); 
do 
        filename=$(basename $a);
        echo $filename
        iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$a" >"/path/to/destination/$filename"; 
done
```

The function basename returns the filename without the path of the file.

**Alternative (user interactive):**
Now I also created a user interactive script that lets you decide whether you want to overwrite the old files or just rename them. Additional thanks go to tbsalling

```
for a in $(find . -name "*.tex");
do
        iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 <"$a" >"$a".utf8 ;
done
echo "Should the original files be replaced (Y/N)?"
read replace
if [ "$replace" == "Y" ]; then
    echo "Original files have been replaced."
    for a in $(find . -name "*.tex.utf8");
        do
            file_no_suffix=$(basename -s .tex.utf8 "$a");
            directory=$(dirname "$a");
            mv "$a" "$directory"/"$file_no_suffix".tex;
        done
else
        echo "Original files have been converted and converted files were saved with suffix '.utf8'"
fi
```

Have fun with this and I would be grateful for any comments to improve it, thanks!