# Bulk convert cp1252 to utf-8 in Windows

Tags: utf-8, cygwin, cp1252

So,
I've been trying to convert a large java source tree from cp1252 to UTF-8 in Windows, using tips and trix I've found online, specificly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9310774). Problem is, I'm on Windows; I don't do VB; Cygwin's iconv doesn't take the `-o` switch.

The line I first tried to use is:

```
find . -type f -print -exec iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 {} > {}.converted \; -exec mv {}.converted {} \;
```

This creates a file `{}.converted` in the working directory and the second `-exec` fails for obvious reasons.

Putting quotes around the iconv expression:

```
find . -type f -print -exec 'iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 {} > {}.converted' \; -exec mv {}.converted {} \;
```

resulsts in the folowing error:

```
find: `iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 ./java/dv/framework/activity/model/ActivitiesMediaViewImpl.java > ./java/dv/framework/activity/model/ActivitiesMediaViewImpl.java.converted': No such file or directory
```

though executing the individual expressions by hand works perfectly.

I've experimented with random quoting but nothing seems to work, what am I missing? Why won't it work..?

Thanx in advance,
Lars

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in `find . -type f`; do
    iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 $f > $f.converted
    mv $f.converted $f
done
```

Comment: Thanx, this works as intended!

But, have you got any idea why the find-exec expression doesn't work? Is it to do with the output redirection..?

Comment: I am not sure, but `-exec` is not preferred. from somewhere I learnt `-exec` can't execute commands that have long arguments. I use `xargs` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Allright, once again answering my own question (this is starting to become a bad habit...)

Allthough there is nothing wrong with Neevek's solution, the perfectionist in me wants to get the find -exec expression right. Wrapping the iconv statement in a `sh -c '...'` does the trick:

```
find . -type f -print -exec sh -c 'iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 {} > {}.converted' \; -exec mv {}.converted {} \;
```

Still, the underlying question of why there is a problem using i/o redirection in find -exec statements remains unresolved...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Cygwin very much but there's a "native" windows version of Iconv that I use all the time.  Here's an excerpt from a batch file that i use to convert all the files in a sub-dir from HP-ROMAN8 encoding to UTF-8 encoding -- putting the result './temp" under the originals:

@set dir=original

@set ICONV="C:\Program Files (x86)\iconv-1.9.2.win32\bin\iconv"

if EXIST .\%dir%\temp (
    erase .\%dir%\temp*.* /Q
    @if ERRORLEVEL 1 (@echo Unable to erase all files from the "temp" sub-directory
      @goto THE_END
    )
  ) else (
    mkdir .\%dir%\temp
    @if ERRORLEVEL 1 (@echo Unable to create the "temp" sub-directory
      @goto THE_END
    )
  )

for %%f IN (./%dir%/*.xml) do (
     %ICONV% -f HP-ROMAN8 -t UTF-8 "./%dir%/%%f" > "./%dir%/temp/%%f"
     if ERRORLEVEL 1 (goto ICONV_ERROR)
  )

Answer (score 0):

The error in the first try is that the redirection operator '>' ist evaluated by the shell before find starts.

The error in the second try is that the text between the single quotes is interpreted as the name of a command that is to be executed by find, but that doesn't exist.

In your working solution the first command to be executed by find is a subshell, and the options are enclosed in single quotes, so they are not interpreted by the outer shell but by the subshell.