# Recursively recode all project files excluding some directories and preserving permissions

Tags: linux, shell, find, recode

How to recursively recode all project files **excluding some directories** and **preserving permissions**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310571/how-to-change-encoding-in-many-files) question, but its solution does not preserve permissions, so I had to modify it.

**WARNING**: since the recursive removal is a part of the solution, **use it on your own risk**

Task:

Recursively recode all project files (iso8859-8 -> utf-8) **excluding** '.git' and '.idea' dirs and **preserving permissions**.

Solution (worked well in my case):

Backup your project's dir, then `cd` there. Run:

`find . -not -path "./.git/*" -not -path "./.idea/*" -type f -print -exec iconv -f iso8859-8 -t utf-8 -o {}.converted {} \; -exec sh -c 'cat {}.converted > {}' \; -exec rm {}.converted \;`

Binary and image files will fail to recode since they aren't text, so files like 'image.jpeg.converted' will be left along with 'image.jpeg'. To clean up this mess:

`find . -not -path "./.git/*" -not -path "./.idea/*" -type f -regex '.*\.converted' -exec rm {} \;`

Before you do that, you may want just print  (without `rm`) to see that there are only those files listed that you'd really like to remove.