# TermDocumentMatrix errors in R

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus, term-document-matrix

I have been working through numerous online examples of the {tm} package in R, attempting to create a TermDocumentMatrix.  Creating and cleaning a corpus has been pretty straightforward, but I consistently encounter an error when I attempt to create a matrix.  The error is:

> Error in UseMethod("meta", x) : 
>     no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In mclapply(unname(content(x)), termFreq, control) :
>     all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code

For example, here is code from Jon Starkweather's text mining [example](http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/Benchmarks/TextMining_L_JDS_Jan2014.pdf).  Apologies in advance for such long code, but this does produce a reproducible example.  Please note that the error comes at the end with the {tdm} function.

```
#Read in data
policy.HTML.page <- readLines("http://policy.unt.edu/policy/3-5")

#Obtain text and remove mark-up
policy.HTML.page[186:202]
id.1 <- 3 + which(policy.HTML.page == "                    TOTAL UNIVERSITY        </div>")
id.2 <- id.1 + 5
text.data <- policy.HTML.page[id.1:id.2]
td.1 <- gsub(pattern = "<p>", replacement = "", x = text.data, 
     ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

td.2 <- gsub(pattern = "</p>", replacement = "", x = td.1, ignore.case = TRUE,
     perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

text.d <- td.2; rm(text.data, td.1, td.2)

#Create corpus and clean 
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
txt <- VectorSource(text.d); rm(text.d)
txt.corpus <- Corpus(txt)
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, tolower)
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, removeNumbers)
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, removePunctuation)
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, stripWhitespace); #inspect(docs[1])
txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, stemDocument)

# NOTE ERROR WHEN CREATING TDM
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(txt.corpus)
```

Comment: I have seen this post, and your question reminded me of that. Have a look of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771165/r-project-no-applicable-method-for-meta-applied-to-an-object-of-class-charact). This may be useful.

Comment: @jazzurro -- thanks so much for redirecting me to this post!  adding content_transformer to the tolower in the tm_map function solved the problem

Comment: I actually had the same problem and saw that post. I am glad that your script is working now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The link provided by jazzurro points to the solution.  The following line of code

```
 txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, tolower)
```

must be changed to

```
 txt.corpus <- tm_map(txt.corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
```

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 reasons for this issue in tm v0.6.

1. If you are doing term level transformations like `tolower` etc., `tm_map` returns character vector instead of `PlainTextDocument`.
   **Solution**: Call `tolower` through `content_transformer` or call `tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)` immediately after `tolower`
2. If the SnowballC package is not installed and if you are trying to stem the documents then also this can occur.
   **Solution**: `install.packages('SnowballC')`

Answer (score 2):

There is No need to apply content_transformer.

Create the corpus in this way:

```
trainData_corpus <- Corpus((VectorSource(trainData$Comments)))
```

Try it.