# TermDocumentMatrix function stops executing in R / RStudio which is a prerequisite for Wordcloud function

Tags: r, word-cloud, term-document-matrix

I have been trying to execute `TermDocumentMatrix` function on my corpus of texts but R and R Studio gave me an

> Error: Error in tdm(txt, isTRUE(control$removePunctuation),
> isTRUE(control$removeNumbers),  :    function 'Rcpp_precious_remove'
> not provided by package 'Rcpp'.

After solving this error by `update.packages('Rcpp') library(Rcpp)` both R and R studio stopped continuing and I have to end R session and R and couldn't proceed to perform `wordcloud` followed by `TermDocumentMatrix` function.
I also googled and search this problem here and read several codes debugging
including [TermDocumentMatrix errors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25551514/termdocumentmatrix-errors-in-r) and [R-Project no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class "character"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771165/r-project-no-applicable-method-for-meta-applied-to-an-object-of-class-charact) but I am still stuck in this code and cannot proceed to provide an amazing visual representation by `wordcloud` and `hist` for most frequent words in my corpus.
I really appreciate any kind of help in this regard.

Here is my entire code:

```
#installing tm package
library(tm)
#loading required package: NLP

#Create Corpus
docs <- Corpus( DirSource('C:/Users/x/Desktop/TextMiningR/Mix22'))
inspect(docs) 
           
#start pre-processing
toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern)  { return (gsub(pattern, " ",x))})

docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "-")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "'")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, " -")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "'")

#remove punctuation 
docs <- tm_map(docs, removePunctuation)

#transfer to lowercase 
docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))

#strip digits
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeNumbers)

#remove stopwords from standard stopword list
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#strip whitespace 
docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)

#inspect output 
inspect(docs)

library(Rcpp)

#create document term matrix : the following line of code stops executing:
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)
#or
dtm <- as.matrix(TermDocumentMatrix(docs))
```

Comment: Just update Rcpp or install the dev version from Github.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rcpp package doesn't include Rcpp\_precious\_remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove)

Comment: Thank you. I updated Rcpp but unfortunately didn't work https://stackoverflow.com/users/10323798/nelsongon. Also, I don't know how to install dev version from GitHub to make the `DocumentTermMatrix` function works.

Comment: Hello again. I want to inform you that my problem was solved by updating R version from 4.0.5 to R 4.1.2. Then, `TermDocumentMatrix ` `wordclound` were smoothly executed.