# R Warning in stemCompletion and error in TermDocumentMatrix

Tags: r, text-mining, tm

I was followed the instruction from [here](http://www.slideshare.net/rdatamining/text-mining-with-r-an-analysis-of-twitter-data)

In slide no. 9 tolower has issue in package tm 0.6 and above I have used

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower)
```

it was duplicate from this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771165/r-project-no-applicable-method-for-meta-applied-to-an-object-of-class-charact/24771621#24771621)
but i still get error when run stemCompletion

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary = myCorpusCopy)
```

And I follow this [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29529990) for both variable myCorpus and myCorpusCopy to PlainTextDocument

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, PlainTextDocument)
```

I was able to execute

```
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, stemCompletion, dictionary = myCorpusCopy)
```

but I get 50 warnings

> There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>       warnings()

and I get all 50 warnings:

> 1: In grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument
>   'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 2: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 3: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 4: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 5: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 6: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 7: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 8: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 9: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 10: In
>   grep(sprintf("^%s", w), dictionary, value = TRUE) : argument 'pattern'
>   has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I try to ignore the warnings and create TermDocumentMatrix()

```
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(wordLengths = c(1,   
Inf)))
```

and I get error:

```
Error: inherits(doc, "TextDocument") is not TRUE
```

Comment: @lukeA stemCompetion work as complete the words example 
`exampl call java code r`
after `stemCompetion` it would become `examples call java code r`

Comment: @lukeA sorry i dun understand where to put the `cbind(rownames(tdm), stemCompletion(rownames(tdm), myCorpus))`  @@

Comment: Please create a reproducible example as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can create a stemmed term-document-matrix and re-complete the stemmed tokens afterwards:

```
txt <- " was followed the instruction from here In slide no. 9 tolower has issue in package tm 0.6 and above I have used "
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(stemming = TRUE)) 
cbind(stems = rownames(tdm), completed = stemCompletion(rownames(tdm), myCorpus))  
#          stems      completed    
# 0.6      "0.6"      "0.6"        
# abov     "abov"     "above"      
# and      "and"      "and"        
# follow   "follow"   "followed"   
# from     "from"     "from"       
# has      "has"      "has"        
# have     "have"     "have"       
# here     "here"     "here"       
# instruct "instruct" "instruction"
# issu     "issu"     "issue"      
# no.      "no."      "no."        
# packag   "packag"   "package"    
# slide    "slide"    "slide"      
# the      "the"      "the"        
# tolow    "tolow"    "tolower"    
# use      "use"      "used"       
# was      "was"      "was"
```

Comment: execute separately or together?
`tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(stemming = TRUE))` 
than execute 
`cbind(stems = rownames(tdm), completed = stemCompletion(rownames(tdm), myCorpus))`
or execute once both

Comment: Obviously, you'll need `tdm` in the 2nd command, which is created in the 1st by using `tdm <- ...`. So doing the 2nd without having done the 1st would through an error because there's no `tdm`.