# Getting Error for DocumentTermMatrix in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, tm

My previous code has been as below -

```css
corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(final_data$comment))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords())
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, 'brw')
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, 'cid')
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, trimws)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```

I am getting following error on last command (DocumentTermMatrix) -

> 'no applicable method for 'meta' applied to an object of class
>   "character"'

Can you please let me know how to fix it ?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771165/r-project-no-applicable-method-for-meta-applied-to-an-object-of-class-charact)

Answer (score 0):

The use of this line of code is causing an issue `tm_map(corpus, trimws)`. The result is a character string instead of the document. This messes up the corpus. If you want to use other function within tm_map that is not part of the tm package, you need to use the function `content_transformer`.

If you change your last line of code to the one below it should work.

```
corpus <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(function(x) trimws(x)))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
```