# Read umlaut from csv file in Rattle

Tags: r, csv, rstudio, rattle

I have searched a lot on Google, but all goes in vain. I am new with RStudio, and trying to use rattle for data mining. I have a file which contains umlaut (German characters such as; ä, ö, ü and ß). I am using Rattle 3.3.0 with RStudio 0.98.1049. When I try to load the file in RStudio, it loads the file perfectly;

However, when I tried to open the csv file in Rattle, it gives this error;

```
An error occured in the following command:

crs$dataset <- read.csv("file:///C:/Users/data_model.csv", dec=",",
na.strings=c(".", "NA", "", "?"), strip.white=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8").


The error message was:

Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec,
na.strings = character(0L)) :    invalid input 'FT-Stütze' in
'utf8towcs'
```

I am running R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance" on 64-bit platform. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: There is a lot of irrelevant information in you post. It will be easier for others to help you if you narrow down the problem. Edit the CSV into the smallest possible example that has the problem, and include a link in your question.

Comment: A user had the same error [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637278/r-tm-package-invalid-input-in-utf8towcs). Have a look.

Comment: @Jeroen I have removed all invaluable text. The real problem is that Rattle is not able to read the file with umlaut (ä, ö, ü and ß). Is there any package that I can include in rattle so that it can transform these text into wcs from utf8... since utf8 can handle German letters as well... or am I missing something?.

Comment: Does that identical `read.csv` line that causes the error in Rattle work in RStudio? You've not explained exactly *how* you've read it in RStudio.

Comment: @Spacedman. I just used read.csv(filename.csv) command and data is stored as a dataframe and then when I use summary() command it has shown me following details:

Comment: Does that (almost) IDENTICAL line that causes the error in rattle work in RSTudio? Its possible that the file *isnt* UTF-8 encoding, and whatever default options `read.csv` is using in RStudio handle it, but Rattle is forcing `encoding="UTF-8"`. I say almost, just do `dataset <- read.csv(....` etc. Not `crs$dataset <- `

Comment: @Spacedman. I just used read.csv(filename.csv) command and data is stored as a dataframe and then when I use head() command it has shown me following details:
**code:**
`data <- read.csv("test.csv")
head(data)`
**outcome:**
_ Task.List                              Baseline.FInish
1  NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-255  2014-08-14
2  NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-153  2014-09-18
3   NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-18  2014-12-17
4  NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-140  2014-09-26
5  NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-158  2014-04-28
6   NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-68  2014-08-22_

Comment: @Spacedman, yup, all lines work fine in R Studio.

Comment: Confirm that: `read.csv("file:///C:/Users/data_model.csv", dec=",",
na.strings=c(".", "NA", "", "?"), strip.white=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")` works in RStudio.

Comment: yes, it is working file on R Studio as I mentioned in the above comments... as an **outcome**

Comment: Final suggestion is you make your data file, or at least one with a line that breaks your rattle, available. My rattle reads UTF-8 just fine.

Comment: I also try to read the similar csv file, removing all the numerical values, just with the German text and the dates, with Rattle, and I got this error;
`An error occured in the following command:

crs$dataset <- read.csv("file:///C:/Users/asyed/Desktop/Testing Bins/R code/test.csv", na.strings=c(".", "NA", "", "?"), strip.white=TRUE, encoding="UTF-8"). 

The error message was:

Error in type.convert(data[[i]], as.is = as.is[i], dec = dec, na.strings = character(0L)) : 
  invalid input 'NeuerMarkt_Ausführungsterminplan-255' in 'utf8towcs'`

Comment: **3rd try** I removed all the German special characters and then read a similar csv file and it gets load and Rattle is also able to analyze data as usual... **findings** 1, rattle is not able to convert the special characters to wcs in my pc. **procedure** as i just replaces all the special characters with (ü -> ue, ä -> ae, ö -> oe) manually. Now the **key-question** is how to make Rattle able to read special characters?.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)