# Transforming emoji text in R

Tags: r, emoji, corpus

Doing some text mining in R. I have a corpus in the region of 25k documents. I'm currently cleaning my corpus and as part of the process I'm translating to lower case. My implementation:

```
createCorpus <- function(corpusData){
    aCorpus <- Corpus(DataframeSource(corpusData))
    ...
    aCorpus <- tm_map(aCorpus,content_transformer(tolower))
}
```

However, for any document text that contains emojis I'm getting the following error. Note, I've removed the *actual* text.

> Error in FUN(content(x), ...) :    invalid input '...' in
>   'utf8towcs'

Now, I've tried adding `str_replace_all(aCorpus$content,"[^[:graph:]]", " ")` *before* transforming to lower case as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794831/1836030). This produces exactly the same error as above, almost as if it hasn't actually done anything.

I have also tried `tm_map(aCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22794831/1836030), which yields the error:

> Error in enc2utf8(x) : argument is not a character vector

I feel like `str_replace_all()` is the correct approach but I must be doing something wrong? How can I remove all emoji characters so that I can clean my corpus?

**EDIT** For clarification, the parameter passed to the function is  a single column data-frame, where each row is a separate document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using:

```
tm_map(aCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x$content), sub = "byte"))
```

In place of:

```
tm_map(aCorpus, function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte"))
```

The issue is that I had to refer directly to the content of the corpus, not just the corpus itself. Achieved by using `x$content` as the parameter rather than merely `x`.