# Trouble with casefold() due to Non-English letters

Tags: r

All I want to do is change the **address** column in **df** to upper case

```
df$address <- casefold(df$address, upper = TRUE)
```

but I keep getting the following error - probably because of the 'I' with an accent

```
Error in toupper(x) : 
  invalid input 'POLÍGONO INDUSTRIAL OLASO' in 'utf8towcs'
```

I know this observation is already upper case, but not all of them are. I don't want to just substitute all of these instances for their English counterpart, mainly because an Eszett (ß) shows up later and I don't know what that would be replaced with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R tm package invalid input in 'utf8towcs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637278/r-tm-package-invalid-input-in-utf8towcs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casefold works as expected with the i accent on my account.

```
> casefold('POLÍGONO INDUSTRIAL OLASO')
[1] "polígono industrial olaso"
> casefold('POLÍGONO INDUSTRIAL OLASO', upper = TRUE)
[1] "POLÍGONO INDUSTRIAL OLASO"
```

For eszett it leaves as is.

```
> casefold('daß')
[1] "daß"
> casefold('daß', upper = T)
[1] "DAß"
```

You may want to check out the package stringr which will translate eszett to SS.

```
> library(stringr)
> str_to_lower('daß')
[1] "daß"
> str_to_upper('daß')
[1] "DASS"
```

But it doesn't work the other way around.

```
> str_to_lower('DASS')
[1] "dass"
```