# How do I convert files between encodings where only some of them are wrong?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I have a large set of nested directories containing PHP, HTML, and Javascript files that *should* all be encoded as UTF-8. However, someone edited several of the files and saved them with ISO-8859-1 encoding. Unfortunately, they're all mixed in with the UTF-8 files.

I'd like to use the `iconv` tool to convert the incorrectly-encoded files to UTF-8 (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544669/batch-convert-latin-1-files-to-utf-8-using-iconv)). Primarily, the problems occur with characters that are valid ISO-8859-1 but invalid UTF-8.

I think an appropriate starting point would be to find all files that contain invalid UTF-8. What's a good way to do this?

I realise this won't catch all of the cases where the wrong character might be displayed. Any further tips on how I might fix this mess?

Comment: Consider having a look at 
[Windows-1252 to UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75810471).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a bit of a hack, but since it's a one-off occurrence then it might be worth it. iconv will complain about invalid encoding if it can't read the file using the encoding you give it. Therefore, you could write a wrapper script to iterate over all the files, attempting to convert them from UTF-8 to something else, and those that can't be converted have invalid UTF-8.

Comment: Cool! That's pretty much what I did: `iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-8 | grep "^iconv"` handled it pretty well.