# Avoid double conversion when converting windows-1250 to utf8

Tags: utf-8, iconv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I convert files between encodings where only some of them are wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726517/how-do-i-convert-files-between-encodings-where-only-some-of-them-are-wrong)

I use the following command to convert .srt files from windows-1250 to utf-8 from a folder

```
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (' dir C:\utf_check\*.srt /b /s ') do %iconv% -s -f windows-1250 -t utf-8 < %%a > %%a.txt
```

I have a problem with this, if the file is already utf-8, iconv breaks the file inserting strange characters. Is there a way to detect first if is utf-8 or ascii then convert it? I tried with flip, enca, encov, recode with no success.

I use Windows 2003 Server, I installed Cygwin too, maybe that would help.

Example: that is the text found in a utf-8 *Aşezaţi-vă.*
and this is the text after iconv is converting again *AĹźezaĹŁi-vÄ.*

Comment: ASCII is subset of UTF-8! (windows-1250 is not, of course)

Comment: ok that i understand already, ASCII is what notepad++ is saying about encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sensible text in windows-1250 encoding will ever be valid utf-8. Because the bytes representing characters beyond ASCII range in utf-8 correspond to sequences of characters in windows-1250 that make no sense. So you need to first check whether the file is valid utf-8 and only if it is not, do the conversion.

You can use the fact, that iconv fails (with errorlevel 1) if it can't do the conversion. So you first run `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8` and if it fails, run `iconv -f windows-1250 -t utf-8`.

Note, that this works only for deciding whether something is utf-8 or legacy encoding but you can't tell between various legacy encodings, because the range of valid characters are the same or mostly so for all windows-*anything* encodings, so you'd have to do some more advanced heuristics, probably involving spell-checker.