# Display text in UTF-8 charset without wrong characters

Tags: php, html, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a text file with some content in it, which I want to display on my webpage. I'm loading the content this way:

```
$txt = file_get_contents('new.txt');
```

When I display the content with `charset=UTF-8` it looks like this:

[image]

When I use `charset=ISO-8859-1` instead it looks like this:

[image]

I want that the Text is looking like the second example, but while using `charset=UTF-8` instead of ISO-8859-1. How can I convert the text so it's displayed right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: If you're sure that all the source text files are in ISO-8859-1 encoding, you may simply use [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert them into UTF-8 before displaying. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21376914/372172) suggests to use iconv through [stream_filter_append](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-filter-append.php), which is a neat trick to handle large files.

Comment: It is worth mentioned that you can simply [find](https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-linux-command-find-2201100) all the text files to batch [iconv](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iconv-command-in-linux-with-examples/) them all. If you are going to have all UTF-8 text files in the future, this is the way to sanitize the old data and thus save your from converting when displaying.

Answer (score 1):

You can either work on the raw data or converting on the fly.

If you're planning to have all new data to stored in UTF-8 format, then batch converting all old data would be more favorable. It is not fun to have mixed encoding in your raw data. You may reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544669/batch-convert-latin-1-files-to-utf-8-using-iconv) to find batch conversion command advice.

On the otherhand, if you're going to keep the input and storage in ISO-8859-1 encoding, the only thing you can do is to convert the document on the fly.

```php
$txt = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8', file_get_contents('new.txt'));
```

Or if your source files have mixed encoding `iso-8859-1` and other unknown encoding, you may add `//IGNORE` flag to prevent error:

```php
$txt = iconv('iso-8859-1', 'utf-8//IGNORE', file_get_contents('new.txt'));
```

This takes more computation power to display the page every time. So it is always preferable to have the raw content converted (unless it is not possible for your situation).