# Winforms Webbrowser Control and Character Encoding

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to use the Winforms `WebBrowser` control to display a webpage that can be in many different languages. In one example, I have a HTML file that has characters in Farsi (examples are not limited to this, however - the file can have Mongolian, Japanese, or any other language).

When I try to `Navigate()` to this file in the `WebBrowser` control, it displays in a bunch of garbled characters (eg. ÓÇÚÊ). If I display the same file in Firefox, however, it will correctly display with all the the expected characters (eg. ساعت). I can also load the raw HTML file in Notepad++ and it seems to automatically detect the character set/encoding that is being used.

I have read numerous threads that talk about setting the `WebBrowser` encoding like so:

`webBrowser.Document.Encoding = "UTF-8"`

however given a set of HTML files, I have no way of telling what language it is written in and therefore no way to know the encoding. I can also confirm there is no "meta" tag within the HTML source that specifies any encoding.

Is there some magic going on behind the scenes of Firefox and Notepad++ to detect the correct character set and if so, how? Can someone tell me how I can get the `WebBrowser` control to behave in a similar way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220608/discussion-on-question-by-simple-guy-winforms-webbrowser-control-and-character-e).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @Bizan pointed out, in the absence of meta tags to describe the encoding, modern browsers seem to [use heuristics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148464/how-do-browsers-determine-the-encoding-used) to determine the language encoding.

Since the `WebBrowser` control is based on dated Internet Explorer technology, it appears there is no in-built logic to do these heuristics automatically.

The solutions are:

- Implement your own heuristics method and then [set the encoding manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902871/wpf-webbrowser-and-special-characters-like-german-umlaute).
- Use the [`WebView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) control (as mentioned by @PanagiotisKanavos) which appears to be use the latest Edge browser. I have tested the pages in Edge and they work correctly. The minimum requirement for `WebView` is Windows 10 however, which will rule out any use-cases where you need your software to run on earlier versions of Windows.