# Unexpected character '�' when compiling C# with special characters on linux

Tags: c#, mono, rider

I just downloaded Mono, Jetbrains Rider and cloned a c# (private) github project.

This project was written in Windows and use Windows-1252 encoding and the source code contains special characters  (á, ç, ã, etc). 
If I try to build this project (both using Rider os MSBuild on bash), I get

> MyFile.cs(16, 3): [CS1056] Unexpected character '�'
>   I configured Rider so it shows the file correctly, but making

```
cat MyFile.cs
```

Shows the � mark symbol.

**Is there anything I have to set on Rider / MSBuild so it reads the files correctly?**

Comment: What encoding do the files use?

Comment: I'm not that proficient in Linux, but that symbol typically represents a character that is missing in your font or character set.  If unicode characters are in use, then make sure you are using UTF-8 instead of ASCII, and that the font you are using supports those international characters.

Comment: @SLaks updated the question: they usw Windows-1252

Comment: @ElementalPete True, but this is a compile error.

Comment: Did you specify `<CodePage>1252</CodePage>` in you `.csproj` file?

Comment: So it seems like Linux is not handling the Windows encoding properly.  See this link for techniques to change the file's encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014069/windows-1252-to-utf-8-encoding

Comment: @ElementalPete I cannot change the file encoding because windows users are using them.