# Finding the encoding of text files

Tags: linux, file, bash, text, encoding

I have a bunch of text files with different encodings. But I want to convert all of the into utf-8. since there are about 1000 files, I cant do it manually. I know that there are some commands in llinux which change the encodings of files from one encoding into another one. but my question is how to automatically detect the current encoding of a file? Clearly I'm looking for a command (say FindEncoding($File) ) to do this:

```
foreach file
do
$encoding=FindEncoding($File);
uconv -f $encoding -t utf-8 $file;
done
```

Comment: `enca` seems to be the tool you are looking for: http://linux.die.net/man/1/enca

Comment: `uconv` should detect the source encoding automatically, i.e. you shouldn't need the `-f` flag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find encoding of a file in Unix via script(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805418/how-to-find-encoding-of-a-file-in-unix-via-scripts)

Answer (score 5):

I usually do sth like this:

```
for f in *.txt; do
    encoding=$(file -i "$f" | sed "s/.*charset=\(.*\)$/\1/")
    recode $encoding..utf-8 "$f"
done
```

Note that recode will overwrite the file for changing the character encoding. 
If it is not possible to identify the text files by extension, their respective mime type can be determined with `file -bi | cut -d ';' -f 1`.

It is also probably a good idea to avoid unnecessary re-encodings by checking on UFT-8 first:

```
if [ ! "$encoding" = "utf-8" ]; then
    #encode
```

After this treatment, there might still be some files with an `us-ascii` encoding. The reason for that is ASCII being a subset of UTF-8 that remains in use unless any characters are introduced that are not expressible by ASCII. In that case, the encoding switches to UTF-8.