# How can I read the "–" character?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am working with Pycharm and I get my data from a separate file. This data contains this character: '–', that looks like a hyphen but apparently isn't.

This isn't an issue as long as I copy the data directly as a string, but if I read it from a file then '–' gets replaced by 'â€“'

Here is a minimal example:

```
with open('data.html', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
print(data)
```

where data.html is:

```
example–example
```

prints:

```
exampleâ€“example
```

I get the same encoding issue when I open data.html with Firefox.
What can I do so that this character is correctly read from the file?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add

```
encoding="utf-8"
```

in your `open()`: `open('data.html', 'r', encoding="utf-8")`

reference: [Hyphen changing to special character â€“](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50985423/hyphen-changing-to-special-character-%C3%A2%E2%82%AC)

Answer (score 0):

try to write code like this

```
with open('data.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
     data = file.read()
print(data)
```