# attempting to run PHP returns php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: pcre2_set_depth_limit_8

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have installed PHP 7.4 through APT, but every time I try to run it, I receive the following error message:

```
php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: pcre2_set_depth_limit_8
```

running the command

```
ldd /usr/bin/php7.4 | grep pcre2
```

returns

```
libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007fa00625e000)
```

running the command

```
nm -gD /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 | grep depth
```

returns nothing, showing that the library does not contain the symbol. However, the library located in

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0
```

does contain the symbol. Running `ldconfig -v` does not appear to have any effect.

Note: I am using PHP, not PHP-fpm

I am using Ubuntu 21.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the symlink in `/usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0` and replacing it to point to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0` seems to resolve this problem. Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: In one shot: `sudo mv /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0 /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0_OLD; sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 /usr/local/lib/libpcre2-8.so.0; php -v`

Comment: @PabloBianchi on every restart I have to do it again and again can you help me with some permanent solution

Comment: Yan Kaf, you may wish to attempt to run the command `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4` as other members have reported this to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

This one helped in my case,

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```